# Should I downvote old, low-quality answers/questions?

Tags: discussion, downvotes, old-questions

Today a question came up that had [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10482339/how-to-find-median) linked as a duplicate.  By today's standards at least the question is pretty bad and some of the answers are too.  Should I bother downvoting those old questions/answers or just worry about more current things?  Does the fact that this older question has been closed as a duplicate of the newer question make a difference

Comment: Does it look like it still wants a downrate? Then yes, downmoat.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you find an older post that deserves a downvote, downvote it. That does not mean you should go and search for these older posts, but if you stumble upon one, do what it deserves. This is what votes are for, use them.

Some people might say don't bother voting on closed questions. I do vote on them. They might be reopened in the future. The question you linked to already received some reopen votes. Might be the meta effect, might be it really should be reopened. I'm not qualified to decide in this case, so I did not take any action :).

Comment: On the flipside, if you stumble upon an old post that deserves an upvote, then by all means cast an upvote!

Comment: @MichaelKjörling And take any other action that you find necessary :).

Answer (score -2):

If an answer is helpful to me, then I upvote it even if the answer is old, so I see no reason why old questions which are **not** helpful or of good quality should not be downvoted. One example I can think of is that someone has edited/defaced the original question in some way such that it is no longer helpful on the original subject of the question.

An exception to this is if a question already has a significant negative rating. In this case I think the OP has "got the message" and there is little point in further downvoting.

Comment: If you see someone defaced a question / answer, please call for mod-attention because someone really needs to be hammered. If it looks reasonable but makes it wrong, explain how the edit was bad. They might decide it is borderline and just roll it back though.

Comment: Some people say we should not downvote if the post already has enough downvotes. I do not agree. I always look at posts as if they did not have any votes yet.