# How on Earth can this kind of question be so appreciated?

Tags: discussion, old-questions, needs-more-focus, popularity, bad-questions

I found the *[Manually raising (throwing) an exception in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2052390/manually-raising-throwing-an-exception-in-python)* question today. No doubt that it has good answers. But the question itself is too broad and doesn't show any research effort. I thought that questions like "How do I do that? (I'm too lazy to read the basic documentation or try something)" are plain not welcome here.

[This question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/306273/old-highly-upvoted-questions-that-dont-follow-current-so-standards) is referring to historical significance of old questions. Please understand - I'm really asking about this specific example of asking for basic language construct which is broadly described in official Python documentation which was available in 2012. Come on. Asking Google `How can I raise an exception in Python` gives https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html as the first result...

Comment: It's six years old and has been viewed 355,100 times. That that particular OP now has 35,500 points may indeed be testament that the reputation system has failed, though

Comment: You are assuming that reading the basic documentation was an option back when the question was asked. Which, while probably true for Python, isn't always the case. Quite a few of those uber popular questions owe their popularity to the fact that documentation was either non existent, or unparseable back then.

Comment: @Yannis I'm not assuming anything. I do know that Python documentation was available in 2012 without a problem.

Comment: So downvote and move on!

Comment: This is 6 years of high Google ranking at work.  Still the 2nd hit when you query "python throw exception", surprising.  0.17% of the programmers that looked at it actually voting it helpful is perhaps not so impressive.

Comment: repgazer's make me puke.

Comment: It's hardly worth getting worked up into a tizzy over a question like that one. It's about 100 times better than the 5 questions that just got posted while I was writing this comment.

Comment: @PeterMortensen I don't think copy editing a closed question is a good idea, because it makes it unnecessarily appear in the reopen votes queue.

Comment: see also: [Should I downvote old, low-quality answers/questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/258800/839601)

Answer (score 16):

To be clear, "How do I do [something]" and "I'm too lazy to try something" are not the same thing.

The reason such questions are so popular is because many people find them useful or interesting.  Like it or not, those questions attracted votes because they attracted views.

If you google "How to foo the bar," what would you prefer to find on Stack Overflow?  A question titled "How to foo the bar" that has an answer that clearly explains how to foo the bar?  Or a question titled "How to foo the bar" that is really just someone's highly-specific problem they encountered while fooing the bar?

I know which one I'd prefer.

The insistence on "What have you tried" has turned Stack Overflow from a general computing resource into a debugging platform.

**Further Reading**
[How to Debug Small Programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: To the downvoter: was I somehow unclear?

Comment: I agree with you. Also, these questions are not what's "valued" in the end, it's all about the quality of the answers. If you post a highly specific, clever and well-structured question, that's good, but you will never get as much attention (and thus answers and upvotes) as someone with a really basic question that anyone in that field could answer within 3 minutes (if even!).

Comment: Not the downvoter, but someone probably found your opinion heretical. Clearly Stack Overflow is meant to be a debugging service.

Comment: @BoltClock: Just another day at the office.

Comment: It's ironic really, because ["what have you tried" is not meant to be taken literally](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/173743/155739) but as a friendly way of prodding the user into _not_ treating SO as a debugging service but instead presenting a well-thought out and broadly-useful question about a programming language. Sadly too many people are too stupid for this to have worked. :)

Comment: @PreferenceBean: That would be news to me, since it is hardly ever interpreted that way.  Why keep using something that never works, that actually causes unintended side-effects?

Comment: @RobertHarvey: Good question.

Answer (score 3):

The site's standards have changed over time. That question would likely no longer fly these days.

I agree it's a bit unfair those old questions get to stand, but they contain too much useful information to be removed altogether.

Comment: I think it's more unfair that new ones that are good don't get the chance to stand.

Answer (score 1):

The attitude towards "bad" questions has changed drastically on SO over the years, and, if you'd ask a question like this nowadays, you'd probably lose a lot of rep.

Just take a look at the other popular questions of that person: they all share the same "bad" style and were also posted between 2009 and 2011, but they still attracted a lot of good questions and were upvoted a ton.