# Let's give the Original Poster a chance to post an appropriate question

Tags: discussion, feature-request, questions

This post is about how SO can help the OP post a good on-topic question, avoiding duplicate, off topic, too broad, and unclear posts that end up in review queues, launch reputation hunts, and finally the OP feels [Why is Stack Overflow so negative of late?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251758/why-is-stack-overflow-so-negative-of-late)

Let's first put ourselves in the new poster's shoes; what are they used to?

[image: Question: "I see some strange char before the incoming xml when a msxml4 service is calling my service"]

*"So let's post!!! (There is a FAQ to study. Sure, I will check that out later. But I'm not writing anything that will offend someone, am I?)"*. OP is hoping that someone answers *"That's probably the BOM Header"*

I have posted, time to work some… I will check on it in a while…

Meanwhile, on SO:

> Down vote, Down vote, Down Vote, Comment, Comment, Closed (Too broad,
> unclear, missing MCVE)—all done by **hard working** community members!—and then some lucky contributor sneaked in an answer and got some rep.

OP comes back, *"What the heck, there is unlike button on SO?"*, *"Why is SO so negative? Who did I offend?"*

What do I think SO should do? Create an ask-a-question interface that helps the OP post a good question—not just title, text, tag, and submit. You need to understand how to ask on SO, you can't post as on Facebook.

This example **does not pretend** to have a complete solution for the interface, but demonstrates some features that can be built in to help the OP, and thus the SO community.

## Start asking a question

**What is your programming language?** Here tags should be inserted and SO should show relevant info about tagging and frequent questions asked, notify the user that they need to monitor the post if it's a high-traffic tag, etc.

**What is your topic?** Here a topic(s) is selected (*Error in application*, *Looking for tool*…).

Let's select "Looking for tool" ---> "Sorry, off-topic" ---> "Okay, I can't post this!"

Let's select "Error in application", this gives us an interface to post an MCVE in.

### Error in application input

> Please debug your application before posting!

And also, let's give some other nice warnings (that help the OP).

- **Title** <kbd>?</kbd>: Let's help the OP get the title correct (as in the *Help and Improvement* queue).
- **Problem** <kbd>?</kbd>: State the problem.
- **Relevant code** <kbd>?</kbd>: Post relevant code to reproduce problem.
- **Current output** <kbd>?</kbd>: State your current output.
- **Expected output** <kbd>?</kbd>: State expected output.
- **Stack Trace** <kbd>?</kbd>: Post relevant stack trace.

  <kbd>SUBMIT</kbd>

## Considerations

**Some positive**

1. Stop honest users from asking off-topic questions.
2. Possibility to automatically format the post.
3. Possibility to search for duplicates in a more advanced manner.
4. Less moderating (comments, editing, close questions, deleting, etc.)
5. More costly to spam
6. More info for bot's to work on.
7. More info to search on.

More happy users -- > More traffic

**Some negatives**

1. Takes longer to ask a question (maybe should be under positives).
2. More difficult to ask a question (well it actually is anyway if you don't want people to down vote and close it).
3. Maybe you can't make an interface particular to every question type (well let's keep an option "other", which gives the normal interface with a nice warning).

*So what is my question in this post?*

> Don't you think, if SO had a more advanced interface to ask a
> question, that this would benefit everybody? If you think so, what can the procedure be to create this?

**EDIT**: The duplicated and its duplicated, points at FAQ solution, and popup.

I'm suggesting a guided interfaces—and probably not only for first-time posters, but for everybody (with the other option). This will force the OP not to ignore the tour, FAQ, and help them into the community.

Furthermore, it seems that answers are suggesting that helping the OP would be good, but with no [status-completed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/status-completed) or [status-declined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/status-declined). Unfortunately, I can not find an answer to my question. What is the procedure to create this?

Comment: Remember that not all questions are going to be able to follow this pre-determined format. Suggestion: add a "I don't need a template" option to go back to the original, and only show this interface for the first-ever user post.

Comment: @gunr2171 I have taught about this, only first time you post?, but why not always use it... (not only first time user have problem with asking a question)... The general question option can always be available (see point 3 in negatives)

Comment: I don't dislike this, but I fear that the list next to `What is your topic:` would either not cover all possibilities, or be insanely large - and the "title / problem / relevant code etc." section would likely overwhelm many newbies, even those with a valid problem.

Comment: @PetterFriberg The first post on SO is "trial by fire". Yes it's true that a lot of people crash and burn on the first try. I'm going to guess that the number of people who   significantly improve on the second post is high.

Comment: @gunr2171: It's important to remember that *before* the first post, the user in question is given the tour of what's appropriate. It's very unfortunate that so many people choose to ignore that... it's not like we're not *trying* to help them.

Comment: @Pekka웃, mine is not a final solution, just a demonstration of what you can achieve.. You can always do a select "Other"... The idea is to help OP!, I love to close use 50CV everyday... but I really would prefer to answer.

Comment: @JonSkeet, the OP has his question in mind, I still remember my first question, SO is overwhelming for a new user. Its take month to learn and understand.

Comment: @PetterFriberg: The details? Absolutely. But the tour only takes 5 minutes to read through, and yet still we end up with *lots* of complete garbage posts from users who have clearly ignored what they've been presented with.

Comment: @JonSkeet I just retook the tour. The [first example question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24001778/do-swift-based-applications-work-on-os-x-10-9-ios-7-and-lower) I am exposed to is barely on topic (will probably be closed soon) and certainly not representative of what we are looking for. Furthermore, the huge "Ask a question" button at the end has no link to "How to Ask". Respectfully, I hardly think the tutorial is supposed to prevent what you imply it's supposed to prevent.

Comment: @user1803551: I believe it is intended to. I suggest you file a feature request / set of bugs about it.

Comment: @JonSkeet, "clearly ignored what they've been presented with", exactly!, since we would like to avoid these (we only loos time cleaning up), can we force the OP to not ignore?, by guiding them.. (I think any good software should do this)

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92939/i-think-stack-overflow-should-convert-to-catholicism-so-that-we-may-have-purgato

Comment: I think there are enough differences between this question and the "additional prompting" question to warrant a separate question.

Comment: @PetterFriberg but since, as Pekka  pointed out, we would need either a "no template", or an EXHAUSTIVE list... we'll start having posters not read the list, pick one line at random, and post anyway..... BECAUSE users ignore the tour, they will ignore this. It'll just end up pissing off good users.

Comment: The first question could be ["Does your code work correctly?"](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35347500/2564301).

Comment: *Furthermore, the huge "Ask a question" button at the end has no link to "How to Ask".* @user1803551 - I see a big button for the Help Center on the tour below the Ask button. Is your argument that the Ask button should take users to the Help Center as well?

Comment: @BSMP My argument is (1) The Help Center button is preceded by "*Looking for more in-depth information on the site?*" to which the reader will automatically answer "*no*" because they already got the idea in the tour. (2) That the button is presented in a manner of "if you ever need me, I'll be here" and not "**read this before you go on**". (3) That before your first "Ask A Question", your option is to visit a help center menu and not [ask].

Comment: Your proposal has one critical flaw: it assumes that Stack Overflow is a troubleshooting tool (and only that).

Comment: @RobertHarvey Why?, no, true that in example I only included this, but its not in any means a final solution, just a demonstration of what could be done to help OP post a good question

Comment: The other critical flaw is thinking that those people aren't perfectly able to push some buttons and put just any junk in your form which let's them ask their question finally, darn it, because they aren't interested in your irrelevant hoops.

Comment: I am saying that your proposal bakes in too many assumptions about site scope.  Aren't we too focused on troubleshooting questions already?

Comment: @Deduplicator, I continue to assume the OP is asking of his best means (and this OP I would like to help). Anyway the system would make more easy to identify bad post by bots (hence more info) and make it more costly to spam.

Comment: @RobertHarvey, tell me which I am missing?, keeping people busy flagging and closing?

Comment: Have a look here: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/316608/102937

Comment: @RobertHarvey, ok I see what you mean, that discussion is far above the scope of this question and maybe when design the interface this could be contemplated... (as is now its the OP that gets in the middle of this fight)

Comment: @user1803551 - If there's info missing from the tour, wouldn't it be better to just put it in the tour itself rather than just using stronger language for a button they're not going to click on anyway?

Comment: @BSMP Yes, it was my intention to purpose adding content from [ask] and [mcve] or something of the sorts. I take my time before posting on meta. Also, I didn't suggest changing the language, the quotes "if you ever need me, I'll be here" and "read this before you go on".describe the manner in which things are presented.

Answer (score 12):

There are a few problems with this proposal.

First, let's look at your actual proposal:

> Create an ask-a-question interface that helps the OP to post a good question (not a title, text, tag, submit). You need to understand how to ask on SO, you can't post as on FB.

## Problem 1: We already have an interface; it's just not as fancy as your proposal.

We *have* "an ask-a-question interface that helps the OP to post a good question." It offers helpful, non-overwhelming, simple-language hints and help on the right side of the screen at each step. It also offers important links. Once the user starts typing, it offers potential existing solutions to the problem (existing questions).

What you're really arguing is simply that the existing interface isn't good enough. Why not? You suggest adding lots of prompts and steps to the question-asking process, but does that really address the problem?

Keep in mind that we get thousands of questions every day, many of which aren't just bad, but completely unintelligible. We also get hundreds of answers posted as questions and questions posted as answers, not to mention "thanks," "me too," and link-only answers, *every single day*. Sadly, many of these aren't even from truly new users. **In other words, people aren't reading the help text that's available to them now.** Consider the text that greets new users who attempt to post an answer

[image: answer prompt]

It says, "Please be sure to *answer the question*," and "*avoid* ... Asking for help, clarification, or responding to other answers." Yet hundreds of people a day completely ignore this. Getting people to follow directions without completely preventing them from acting is *hard*.

Why would your solution fix that? It's not clear to me from what you've posted.

## Problem 2: One size does not fit all.

As you acknowledge in your question and as people have pointed out in the comments, one interface can't fit all decent questions. Many good questions don't involve all of the factors you list, even for the specific topic of "error in application." In fact, many good questions don't even involve *most* of these factors.

Worse than that: this interface would only be useful on SO. It wouldn't apply to the other [Trilogy](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/256420/238426) sites (Server Fault and Super User) without significant tweaking, and it wouldn't apply to other SE sites at all without a complete overhaul. On the other sites where I am active, I'm not sure how it would even work. So, it's an SO-specific burden for the developers. Site-specific changes to the code are usually disfavored, and the reasons for them need to be very compelling.

## Problem 3: We don't actually need this.

The whole concept of SO/SE is to use voting and community moderation to help good questions and answers rise to the top *and to force bad ones down*. That's why we have downvotes. I'm far from convinced that extra hand-holding is going to help a user who posts a question here without even noticing that we have up *and down* buttons next to every post. Not to be harsh, but if you really know and understand that little about the site, you're unlikely to ask a good question, no matter how hard we try to help you.

## Conclusion

I really don't think this would help enough to merit the effort it would require. It would be a big undertaking for the SO development team, would not port directly to other SE sites, and would only help to the extent that users are paying attention when asking questions. But... if a user is paying attention when asking a question, he or she is already unlikely to post garbage, anyway.

Comment: Thanks for taking time to answer, these are my brief comments, related to the problems. 1) OP is concentrated on posting question, text at the side or FAQ are just noise (and as you state this is obvious), a new interface would generate focus on how it's asked, what to include and filter away obvious close reasons. 2) Related to select this seems like a minor problem, as stated you can always choose other and have old. While trilogy sites I have no clue (SO is big enough for this development?)

Comment: 3) I feel overwhelmed by all bad question (close que), sad about all angry OP, and worry about the content.. but ok.. lets just "pack it" and sweep the top. Conclusion: I can only see benefits... and I will include some more like spam blocking, search features ecc.

Comment: @PetterFriberg I don't think the text on the side is noise. It's the warning you get to say, "Hey, this is different, pay attention for a couple of seconds!"

Comment: Sorry I used wrong term, I meant "people aren't reading the help text that's available to them now"

Comment: @PetterFriberg re the bad questions and angry posters: you wouldn't believe how bad it really is. The flag queue is unreal. But that's part of my point. We have some very, very experienced users who still don't seem to "get' how the site works because people don't read directions. The feedback people get from comments, closed questions, and downvotes is much more powerful at saying "You're doing it wrong" than any walkthrough or pop-up tips could ever hope to be.

Comment: What is important is that I actually like to help OP, helping everybody, the example I made is a true example, its my [first question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32786245/what-is-this-socket-heading-bytes-chars-before-receiving-the-actual-xml-from). It did not end up as in example, luckily Alex K. come by and I started to contribute. If as in example in this question probably I would not. When I finally got the possibility to "Improve and Edit" I finally understood a little bit on how to ask, I even go to the que just to check it out, not only for review.

Comment: @PetterFriberg Please don't misunderstand me; I want to help people, too. The problem is that so many of the garbage posts aren't fixable. Whether people aren't reading, have a language barrier to deal with, or (in some cases) are just stubborn, lots of posters just never fix their messes. I'm all for anything that helps fix that, but it has to (1) work and (2) not cause undue problems elsewhere (e.g., preventing people from asking good questions, scaring away new users who are really trying, etc.). I'm just not convinced this proposal would do those things.

Comment: Ok, remember there are a lot of good user out there and they need all the help you can give them to make them stay. They need a fair chance and the FAQ, popup for me is not enough. We need to help them more... about the garbage post, think of what you need to block them before they arrive, what can be done in the interface. (you will not get them all, but surely you will have more indications, for bot building etc)

Comment: Final note, this post is not about answering only about helping you to ask.

Comment: @PetterFriberg Understood. I'm talking about answers because they illustrate the point: many people can't be bothered to comply with the most basic rule that answers should be answers. These are, in my experience, the same people who post garbage questions. More hand-holding might slow them down, but it seems to have no deterrent effect.

Comment: 2 years later, finally we got [ask-a-question-wizard-prototype](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/369682/ask-a-question-wizard-prototype?cb=1) :), I must say that I have some satisfaction in seeing my downvoted meta implemented by SE :P