# Guidance for writing question

Tags: feature-request

Much like in the bio, when it is blank you get the following example:

[image]

For a new user, or user with low rep, I propose something similar to the above might help in writing better quality questions. Though I could be naive here.

```
What have you tried

What was the result

What did you want to the result to be
```

For higher rep users, there would be no need to show this. It might help new users structure questions, that are likely to have enough detail to answer.

Comment: seems similar to https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/316681/lets-give-the-original-poster-a-chance-to-post-an-appropriate-question#316681 or https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260039/could-some-bad-questions-be-avoided-with-additional-prompting

Comment: Possibly the biggest problem with placeholder text is that the moment you start typing in he input box the placeholder text goes away. Take a look at any site discussing UX and you'll see why they're ofte done badly.

Comment: @DavidG That's right. It's especially a problem when the text is long like OP's example.

Comment: A problem with this is that there are a *lot* of perfectly legitimate formats for a Stack Overflow question to take. You've given a template here for a *debugging* question, but - and I repeat this over and over on Meta - most good Stack Overflow questions (and most of the highest-voted questions on the site) are *not* debugging questions. Any non-harmful implementation of this feature, in my view, would need to somehow let the user choose a question *paradigm* first (like "why doesn't this code work?" or "what does this high-level concept mean?" or "how do I do this task?").

Comment: @MarkAmery, yes that's a problem, but still, the cv queue is completely broke (votes are just ageing away), SO is being flooded with "debugging questions" without mcve, and other off-topic posts. Since the community can not handle the flood, I believe SO sooner or later needs to tackle this problem and one point on the agenda could be to address first posters interface.

Comment: I realize there are many other types of valid question formats. Asking for a paradigm first, might be a good solution to that issue. I was really seeing this as just a last resort, to get first time users to think before writing. That first page when they go to ask a question for the first time, I imagine most just tick the box at the bottom and continue on without reading. But that's just my speculation.

Comment: @Mark Amery I think it would be a good idea to check what percentage of questions asked by new users are debugging questions. I presume the number will be quite high, so setting the placeholder to this kind of question makes sense (that is, if I'm right).

Comment: @Kapol I agree with your prediction (that most questions by new users will be debugging questions), but disagree strongly with the conclusion you draw from it (that it's fine to use a template that presumes a debugging question is being asked). One cultural problem the site currently has is a significant minority of users who believe that *only* debugging questions are allowed here, asking "what have you tried?" in response to any question they see that doesn't contain the asker's broken code attempt at a solution. I fear this template, if implemented, would fuel and legitimise that behaviour.

Comment: Even if placeholder text isn't the best way to achieve this, something to this effect **really** needs to be done. This would save the need for the obligatory comments requesting this information. New accounts could have a small banner across the top with these suggestions.

Comment: Maybe rather than placeholder text, a checklist with actual checkboxes that the user has to check before the "Submit" button is enabled. Each checkbox would be something like "Provided MCVE", "Explained what I tried", "Explained what resulted from my effort", "Explained what I wanted instead", etc. Maybe have a top-level category, to refine the checkbox list (since not all questions are debugging questions...though, most still should have a MCVE). Granted, some users will just check right through them, but at least it's a reference for the more conscientious.

Comment: @MarkAmery: _"asking "what have you tried?""_ -- IMHO, every single question posted to Stack Overflow should be preceded by _some_ kind of effort by the OP to solve it themselves. Maybe they aren't debugging questions, but "what have you tried?" applies equally well read as "what research have you done and what did you find?"

Comment: BTW what are *C+ Jokes*?

Comment: @GOTO0 something about vitamins

Comment: @PeterDuniho Re: "what have you tried?": I completely disagree. [This answer by Shog9](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260909/4639281) sums it up nicely. If the user has not shown sufficient research effort, then it should be easy enough to close it as a duplicate.

Comment: @TinyGiant The aim here is to get them to write down what they have tried, so we don't have to ask further questions, or go through the close procedure. If they still don't, we can close, but a lot of first time users only tell you what they have tried, after you ask them in a comment. The aim of this isn't to change procedures, but to make users more aware of requirements for a good question.

Comment: I honestly don't care what users have tried most of the time. All I want is a clear and concise question. If all of the details necessary to adequately answer the question are _in_ the question, there is no need for a failed attempt. Not only that, but I often find the failed attempt to be noisy, and it tends to turn the question _into_ a debugging question. @AdamPedley

Comment: @TinyGiant: _"I completely disagree"_ -- disagree with what? You don't think a good question needs to include evidence of effort? I do disagree that lack of effort necessarily translates into "close as duplicate"; the two concepts are completely orthogonal (conflating the two implies that with sufficient research, a duplicate would have been found by the OP and so they wouldn't need to ask their question). But, you seem to agree that a question showing lack of effort should be closed, so how is that a disagreement with what I wrote?

Comment: @TinyGiant: _"I honestly don't care what users have tried most of the time"_ -- for debugging questions, having the OP explain what they've tried can shorten the third-party debugging process. It also helps the OP frame their question with a good MCVE that shows what they've tried. For more conceptual questions, having the OP explain what they've tried, along with why that didn't work, helps constrain the question so that potential answerers can understand what type of answer the OP needs, and what types of answers won't actually address the question.

Comment: @TinyGiant: You could argue that if only the OP would just provide a well-written question in the first place, none of this would be needed, but surely you know as well as any of the rest of us how infrequently that happens. Asking "what have you tried" is a way of guiding the question author in a direction that leads them to naturally provide the details necessary to make the question a good one.

Comment: @Peter did you read the linked post? There are three kinds of _"effort"_. Research effort is handled by closing as a duplicate. Definition effort is handled by closing as unclear, too broad, etc. Problem solving effort (which is what I think you're actually referring to) is hugely subjective to judge. Don't worry about the person asking the question, answers should be for the masses. If it helps, imagine that the question was output by a machine, you can ask for clarification, but you wouldn't demand that a machine put more effort solving the problem that you are being presented with. (1/2)

Comment: For debugging questions, asking what the OP has tried is a reasonable thing to do. Including an MCVE is mandatory for debugging questions, so that is a given. But 'How do I do X?' questions, conceptual questions, high-level concept questions, etc do not need a back story.  As I said before, what I hope for, above all else, is a clear and concise question that is going to be useful for future viewers. Next to that I want as little noise as possible. (2/2)

Comment: @TinyGiant: sorry, I don't get your objection. On the one hand, you seem to agree that questions that lack effort should be closed. On the other hand, you disagree that it's useful to encourage the author of a question to put in some effort, by reminding them that their question needs to have evidence of effort. In any case, I'll remind you that the down-vote tooltip specifically mentions evidence of "research effort" as something that, when lacking, deserves a down-vote. IMHO, this is yet another reason to remind question authors to "show their work".

Comment: My only response to your last comment would be to repeat what I said about the three different types of effort. As I have already done that once, I'm not going to do it again. @Peter