# Practical suggestions on welcoming communication

Tags: discussion, etiquette, writing-style

This question is motivated by [Joel Coehoorn's answer to *Can we do more than just deleting rude comments?*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/365888/2751851):

> Answering or commenting on a question is critical by it's nature, and it's harder to be nice while being critical at the same time. Or perhaps it's too easy to be meaner than we need to be. But there are simple things we can do when answering or commenting on a question that help.
>
> Here's an example. [...]
>
> But that's just one thing. It's a play in a playbook. Something we should be asking is how we can collect these plays, these little techniques, to **grow the playbook**, and then **communicate this playbook to other people** who predominately answer and comment on questions.

Which writing tricks and techniques you find helpful to make your posts and comments more welcoming, sympathetic and/or positive?

---

A few meta remarks about this question. The intent here is not building a manual of style, or any similarly prescriptive purpose (this should address the hypothetical "don't tell me how to be nice" objection alluded to by Nisarg). Rather, the aims are collecting suggestions that we -- individually -- might choose to make use of, and raising any associated communication issues and nuances for further reflection and discussion. This could give us something akin to a survey of the landscape, coalescing some of our knowledge about communication styles that currently is either tacit or spread across a thousand Meta posts. That being so, the question is intentionally broad (party like it's 2008!), but in a manner that, I believe, is acceptable in Meta.

On a final note, title suggestions (and edits) for this question are most welcome. (I originally went for "Positive communication playbook", but that was rather vague, and could be read as overtly prescriptive.)

Comment: I made a playbook over at http://idownvotedbecau.se, and take pull requests on the reg.

Comment: @Will:  In reference to a comment [I just made on that answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/365811/can-we-do-more-than-just-delete-rude-comments/365888#comment573669_365888), this feels like it's a lot closer to the *right* of the spectrum.

Comment: What do the downvotes on the question mean? *We don't want to be nice*, *Don't tell me how to be nice* or *This is pointless*?

Comment: @Nisarg "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful"

Comment: @Nisarg:  "This is pointless" falls under "not useful" for my purposes...

Comment: @Will That is a different take on the matter (and somewhat more narrowly applicable); in any case, it also has its place.

Comment: @Nisarg I see two other possibilities: "This sounds too prescriptive" (which wasn't my intention at all - I welcome edits to make it clear it's not about prescription or enforcement) and "there is too much concern about communication styles in Meta lately" (which would be a fair reason for downvote, even though I of course disagree).

Comment: A simple trick I learned over the years is to disassociate the code from the programmer that posted the question.  Treating it like it invaded his cubicle and is holding him hostage against his will.  Tends to be accurate for the way somebody got into trouble.  So for example instead of saying "your code is wrong", say "the snippet has a bug".  Big, big difference.

Comment: @HansPassant "Treating it like it invaded his cubicle and is holding him hostage against his will. Tends to be accurate for the way somebody got into trouble." -- Nice way of putting it! I will experiment with using "the problem" instead of "your problem" in my answers.

Comment: SOCVR maintains lists of autocomments [here](https://github.com/SO-Close-Vote-Reviewers/auto-comments/tree/master/sites/stackoverflow.com)

Comment: Before commenting, my rule of thumb is: *If in doubt, say it out aloud.* In almost all situations, you will realise whether the tone and content are suitable. Note: this doesn't mean the result is the *best way*, but at least you avoid being rude.

Comment: @jpp apparently [XKCD also thought of that](https://xkcd.com/481/) :)

Comment: Before the fifth vote comes in: What is the point of closing this question (and no, merely quoting the close reason text won't be enlightening)? What is the gain in doing it? While "too broad" is also questionable, I find "primarily opinion based" just perplexing: this is no more opinion based than any other Meta [discussion] about communication styles in Stack Overflow; also, the "Which writing tricks and techniques *you find helpful* [...]" qualifier should be enough to discourage arbitrary answers (i.e. those not grounded on, at a minimum, relevant argumentation or anecdotal evidence).

Comment: See also: [*How to vote to close questions and be welcoming at the same time?*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/366682/2751851)

Comment: @Will FWIW, while I grok the intent behind it, I don't like http://idownvotedbecau.se/ (or canned comments in general), avoid using it personally, and wish others wouldn't use it either. I find that canned comments almost never apply *perfectly* to any particular question, and as such I find them generally unhelpful and disrespectful to the person they're addressed to; if we're going to comment explaining downvotes, it should be to point out *precisely* the problems we see, not to point the user to a [vague page of generalities](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/).

Comment: @MarkAmery Though that site has good advice that can be useful through a supplementary link in a comment (which is roughly what I meant when I said above that "it has its place"), I also dislike canned comments. There is a line of thought according to which canned comments are a good thing because they are the only way to ensure polite and non-snarky comments. I find that stance quite baffling.

Comment: @duplode I agree; I find canned comments impolite in general, and the tone that they typically end up written in to be condescending. I'd far rather receive sharp criticism than a canned comment. A short but relevant discussion, if you haven't already seen it: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/365929/practical-suggestions-on-welcoming-communication/365966#comment585196_365966

Comment: I don't have the time or desire to rewrite the same exact comment over and over. Nor can a comment fully cover what's wrong with a question, why the community has decided to moderate it, and how to bring the question back in line with community standards. That's the point of the website. You are not required to drop a bare link. You are not required to create a canned comment containing the link. You are not required to craft a personalized comment referring to the link as a resource to help the poster understand. **That's all up to you**. Don't blame me for how people link to IDVB.

Answer (score 10):

When pointing out issues with someone else's post, I find it helpful to focus on exactly two things, in this order:

1. *Actionable* suggestions for improving it. Making them actionable is key: rather than reproaching the OP, the goal should be helping them to improve their post. (By the way: when writing comments to new users, any opportunity to slip in an `[edit]` shortcut should be taken.)
2. Pointing out, in a few words, why does it matter. That can dispel the impression that we are being pedantic, and also provides an opportunity to note that improving the post will also be useful for the OP.

Example:

> "I haven't been able to formulate this case without getting syntax errors." -- Which errors, and how you got to them? Please [edit] that into your question. (A question which tells the full story leads to less work for everyone and to better answers.)

Comment: Here is another frequently occurring one: "We cannot run code in an image, and if we have to re-type it, we may introduce additional errors". Oh and of course the blatantly obvious "If you don't show your code, we cannot tell for certain what's wrong with it".

Comment: @usr2564301 Those are good (and common!) examples too.

Answer (score 9):

[Hans Passant's comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/365929/practical-suggestions-on-welcoming-communication#comment573830_365929) makes for a good answer:

> A simple trick I learned over the years is to disassociate the code from the programmer that posted the question. Treating it like it invaded his cubicle and is holding him hostage against his will. Tends to be accurate for the way somebody got into trouble. So for example instead of saying "your code is wrong", say "the snippet has a bug". Big, big difference.

[Joel Coehoorn's example](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/365888/2751851), which I omitted from this question for the sake of brevity, goes in a similar direction, though the motivation put forth there is somewhat different.

Answer (score 3):

This post isn't about how we treat certain groups. It's about the **language** we use when we communicate. Specifically, I am talking about **choice of words** and **style**.

*Nobody* uses sarcasm or hyperbole *as the norm* in their communication style. It is used invariably for emphasis, and online is **easily magnified by context**. For example, the same sarcastic comment will have a different impact on a user seeing -10 on their question versus one seeing +5.

While finding statistics is difficult or impossible to support this argument, I firmly believe that there are some **clear guidelines** which *can* help us communicate better. These guidelines are driven by common sense more than analysis.

**Don't**

- Be sarcastic (Do you have google?)
- Use hyperbole (I'd rather jump off a cliff than tutor you.)
- Sound patronizing (Try reading the docs. [with no granular link])
- Be abrupt (You're wrong. You're wrong there too. You're wrong always.)

**Do**

- Upvote comments instead of adding identical advice in a wittier way.
- Step away when there's a disagreement. The purpose of comments is for clarification.
- Be patient. Expect a few hours for a user to respond.
- Respect but not be ruled by competition. Don't compete to hound OP.

I don't claim to follow all the above advice. We all have to adjust. There are external factors (entitlement culture; loss aversion; positive-only social media) which make SO daunting for new users. While regulars may spend much of their time on SO, this is probably not true for most questioners.

Comment: `Do you have google` is not always sarcastic. Some countries have it blocked or accessing it is not easy. `You're wrong` is a fact. When someone is wrong, in a verifiable field, telling them they're wrong is good for them. It's not an issue. `Expect a few hours for a user to respond.` No, absolutely not. When someone posts a question, they should make themselves available for answering the comments or clarifying points. They should absolutely not dump their request and go away while volunteers do all the work for them.

Comment: @Moritz "When someone is wrong, in a verifiable field, telling them they're wrong is good for them." -- Indeed, but we don't necessarily have to say that literally as "you are wrong", which is overtly confrontational. `"[quote of wrong statement]" -- Not really, because [explanation of what is wrong]` is just as good in getting the point across. Cf. [the answer I made out of Hans' comment here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/365990/2751851).

Comment: @Moritz, Do you have a source for `They should absolutely not dump their request and go away while volunteers do all the work for them`? Frankly, if someone wants to post a question before going on a long-haul flight, that's fine by me. If it's a good question, it will be answered. If not, it will be downvoted and/or closed.

Comment: @jpp "Thank you for demonstrating the problem. Comments are for clarification" -- Though I don't agree with most of it, I think Moritz's comment is fine from a procedural point of view. Pointing out perceived issues with an answer is a legitimate use of comments, and arguably counts as a form of asking for clarification. More generally, I don't think enforcing "comments are for clarification" in a very strict and literal way is a good idea, for the reasons mentioned in [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/366012/2751851).

Comment: @duplode `we don't necessarily have to say that literally as "you are wrong", which is overtly confrontational` That's where we disagree. :) I think it's just a fact, to me it's not mean or anything. We're talking to programmers. If something is wrong, we should say it. In my opinion.

Comment: @jpp the source for "They should absolutely not dump their request..." is in the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) help article, the section titled "Post the question and respond to feedback".

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan, This is advice **for the asker**, not *for the answerer*. From the answerer's perspective, a good question (even if the asker leaves SO straight after posting) may still be worth answering. If the question is lacking, then you may altruistically ask for clarification, but it is not a requirement, nor should you do so with any expectation.

Comment: @Moritz "We're talking to programmers" -- I feel the matter is quite independent of whether we are talking to programmers or not, though your comment does suggest a few interesting questions about professional ethos. Your remarks remind me of Martin James' views on the matter -- "there is nothing as pedantic as a compiler" (I'm quoting one of his recent comments from memory) -- which I ultimately disagree with. I am not a compiler :)

Comment: @duplode The thing is, I'm like that "IRL", blunt and straight to the point, with a smile. It works very well with professionals or people willing to be ones. "You're wrong here" - "How yeah, oops, let me fix that". // I understand, though, that it probably doesn't work as well in written form, when the tone is absent and there's only the words left.

Comment: @jpp I think part of the reasoning for questions is also true for answers. From the article, amended: "If you missed an obvious piece of information, be ready to respond by editing your `[answer]` to include it". Seems like good advice.

Comment: @Moritz Good reminder on tone and non-verbal cues -- we end up having to make some adjustments to account for the lack of them. By the way, I think this is the first time I have seen this issue being raised in all of the discussions related to the Welcoming blog post, which in hindsight is kind of surprising.

Comment: Also, something surprising to me on this site, is that people see the harshness in comments but don't see it in the poster's attitude. When someone dumps barely formatted homework and leaves for hours, I call this insulting and disrespectful. It says "hey plebs, do the work for me, better be good and ready when I come back tomorrow". This is *so* harsh and abusive. That's what I wanted to point out with my first comment, but I probably didn't explain myself very well.

Comment: *"Were are talking to programmers"* – The thing is, there's a wide variety of "programmers". Not everyone has the same personality type. Not everyone is used to blunt, direct-to-the-point communication. Not everyone is a *professional* programmer [just yet]. Even programmers are first and foremost *people*, and there's a whole lot of those with a whole lot of squishy personality…

Comment: @duplode I just read the answer by Hans that you [linked](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/365990/2751851), I missed that earlier. This is interesting. I'm not convinced it would suddenly solve the issues that are talked about in this Q&A (and everywhere on Meta these days), but I'll make an effort in this direction if that helps at least a little bit, sure.

Comment: @Moritz [1/2] I don't think, too, that it will solve everything on its own (in particular, because there is also another side of the problem that has to do with effectively communicating, through the "onboarding" of new users, what we are actually trying to achieve here), but I'm convinced and hopeful that it can help.

Comment: @Moritz [2/2] By the way: I fully agree that things like homework dumps and reposting with multiple accounts are rude and abusive. The caveat I would add is that not all people who post problematic first questions are acting in bad faith, and that we shouldn't paint all new users with the same brush. For instance, I find the attitude shown in [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/366970/2751851) to be misguided. [Jared Smith's answer there](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/367249/2751851) makes this point in an elegant way.

Answer (score -1):

In the SQL community I have noticed a great habit of pointing out SQL Injection related issues to the asker (*whether or not they are relevant to the question*). Here are some samples of such comments:

> Hey, welcome to stack overflow. This is just a friendly reminder that your code is vulnerable to MySQL injection. You should consider using [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) as this code is not suitable for production - [IsThisJavascript](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3961074/isthisjavascript) - [Comment Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48748776/php-updating-product-table-quantity-while-fetching-data-from-another-table#comment84497687_48748776)
>
> Also, your code is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. You should use parameterised queries and prepared statements to help prevent attackers from compromising your database by using malicious input values. [bobby-tables.com](http://bobby-tables.com/) gives an explanation of the risks, as well as some examples of how to write your queries safely using PHP / mysqli. **Never** insert unsanitised data directly into your SQL. - [ADyson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5947043/adyson) - [Comment Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48764605/form-doesnt-send-post#comment84529818_48764605)
>
> **Danger:** You are **vulnerable to** **[SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/)** that you need to [defend](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) yourself from. - [Quentin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19068/quentin) - [Comment Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48784859/next-button-and-show-data-one-at-a-time#comment84571598_48784859)

This is valuable advice, given that a lot of beginners might not realize their mistakes until there is a security audit, or worse - a breach. I suppose we could share best practices (or warn against poor practices) for other technologies as well.

Comment: Though I'm not sure about how well this generalises to other "best practices", warning about red flag issues such as SQL injections is certainly considerate.

Comment: We no longer have to: https://xkcd.com/327/

Comment: [xkcd 327 explained](https://explainxkcd.com/wiki/index.php/327:_Exploits_of_a_Mom)

Answer (score -2):

Just the other day I saw a motivational poster with a saying:

> Speak only after your words have passed these gates:
>
> - Are they true?
> - Are they necessary?
> - Are they kind?

I think that about sums it up.

Comment: Realising that what you'd say fails any of these spares you from worrying about the other two. In particular, asking "will this really add anything that matters to what I'm saying?" can avoid a lot of trouble.

Comment: "What have any of those bullet points have to do with getting my homework answer now?  It's just noise - I cannot hand in irelevant bullet points.  You lot on SO are totally clueless, just get my homework done.  Don't you know your place?  We are in charge here!  Any more backchat and I, and my other 20 voting-ring buddies, will dump so many rude flags on you that you won't be able to breathe for a year"

Comment: @MartinJames, SO is happy to help professional and enthusiast programmers. To understand the ways we can help, please do visit our [advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask/advice) page. We would be delighted to assist if your question is in scope.

Comment: @MartinJames The primary concern (for the lack of a better expression) here is with users engaging in good faith. If that is not the case, we can still (1) Gracefully *tell them the truth*, if they left any space for dialogue; and (2) carry out the appropriate moderation actions.

Comment: *Fire fuels fire.* I often here Meta users say, "It's understandable, answerers are burned out," or "Well, what about the rudeness of questions?" or "They communicated with disrespect first," or "Communicating respectfully hasn't worked in the past, we need to have a harder line." The fact is, being harsh is likely to prolong a difficult conversation. Be nice, flag their rude comment, then move on.

Comment: [slatestarcodex.com's comment policy](http://slatestarcodex.com/comments/) requires all comments to pass *two* of these three gates, and the blog owner providers his reasoning for why this is so. It also provides some amusing insight into the source of this advice.

Comment: @jpp Your hypothetical response to Martin is an excellent example of why I think the recent proposals of leaning more heavily on pre-written agreed-to-be-civil prose is a terrible idea. You think it's polite, but if I were on the receiving end, I'd perceive it as condescension and contempt. It's passive aggressive; you're effectively telling me 1) my question sucks, 2) you don't care enough to tell me how it sucks, and 3) you assume I haven't already read the help section. Worse still, it's all in a tone calculated to stop me accusing you of rudeness without actually showing me any respect.

Comment: @MarkAmery, That *is* interesting feedback. I was aiming to avoid absolutely any obvious indication of disgust (no sarcasm, hyperbole, etc). If this response doesn't work, then I'd go so far as to say maybe *comments as a concept don't work*. Others have raised this opinion too.

Comment: @jpp In fairness, April Wensel would likely consider your comment to be the epitome of politeness; her Twitter feed is full of her taking blunt Stack Overflow comments and rewriting them in exactly the (to my ears, smug and patronising) style you've tried above. I, on the other hand, consider bluntness to be part of showing respect to one's professional peers. The real trick, if you could pull it off, would be to find a writing style that offends neither my sensibilities nor April Wensel's.

Comment: @jpp As for comments as a concept not working; I think they work fine. Negative feedback is crucial to the site's functioning. You just have to accept that it will sometimes upset the recipient, because every possible style of writing negative feedback will be perceived as especially and gratuitously insulting by *some* people. Certainly, downvotes *without* comments aren't perceived by user's as non-insulting either, as evidenced by Meta threads demanding explanations for them, so just suppressing critical comments outright, besides all the other reasons it'd be awful, doesn't solve anything.

Comment: [1/2] @MarkAmery That two-out-of-three comment policy is a very interesting formulation. I feel it is a good heuristic even for Stack Overflow comments, though of course the devil lies in the details of what counts as "kind" or "necessary".

Comment: [2/2] MarkAmery and @jpp  : "The real trick, if you could pull it off, would be to find a writing style that offends neither my sensibilities nor April Wensel's" -- "Please \[edit\] your question to point out a specific issue you had while trying to solve this problem. Exact reproductions of homework problems are not a good fit for this site, as questions here should be useful not just to askers, but to other readers." Does this pass the test? (Note this assumes Martin's hypothetical aggressive comment, which would call for a rather different approach, hadn't been posted -- not yet, at least.)

Comment: @duplode It's certainly fine by me, tone-wise, but probably not flowery and cheerful enough to meet April's demands, as I understand them. But you'd need to ask her.