# Redesign question comments UI to encourage higher quality and nicer comments

Tags: feature-request, comments

Recently there has been a very useful [discussion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/365811/324364) about how to better moderate rude comments. Most of the discussion there has focused on flagging, deleting comments, warning users when their comments have been flagged, etc. (This feature request began as an [answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/365986/324364) on that question.)

These are all moderation efforts premised on the continued existence of the comment UI as it currently exists. However, a [comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/365811/can-we-do-more-than-just-delete-rude-comments#comment573016_365849) by Shog9 resonated with me:

> Fwiw, the level of false negatives is high for all comment flag types;
>   relatively few comments get flagged period, even when they unarguably
>   should be. **There are too many comments.** – Shog9♦ 2 days ago

(Emphasis added.)

There are too many comments!

Stack Overflow has dealt for many years with the "problem" of too many questions and has built up a huge array of UI designed to increase the friction of asking in ways that guide people toward higher quality questions.

In addition to the moderation techniques discussed, I wonder if we should also consider a complete redesign of the question comment UI to make it harder to leave comments and to use a much heavier hand in guiding users toward *good* comments.

Comments under questions are primarily intended for one purpose: to elicit clarifications on questions to make them clearer and more answerable. The current UI does almost nothing to guide users toward that end.

Consider some of the following hypotheticals:

- **The text link under a question should read "request a clarification" not "add a comment"**. This is such a simple and easy thing that could reframe the user's mind toward the purpose of a "comment". The subsequent button should be labelled "post your request" not "add comment", etc.
- **The text box shown to the user could be pre-populated with a prompt, geared toward a polite request for more information**, e.g. "Could you please provide more information about" with the cursor placed at the end. The user could remove the prompt, but again it adds more friction.
- **If there are pre-existing "comments" the user could be forced to move through a dialog box first giving them the option to simply up-voting an existing "comment".** Again, the user would be able to dismiss the dialog, but more friction.
- **The asker could be shown a "clarify question" text with no option to leave their own comment**. That linked text could take them *directly* to the question editing UI, annotated with the clarification requests and prompts to address them directly in the question text.
- Miscellaneous: smaller tweaks might include removing the ability to @ users other than the asker in comments and reducing the character maximum.

I am far from a UI design expert, so take all that more in the spirit of a general idea than the specifics. The point would be make it *much* less appealing to add comments in general and to use a much heavier hand to funnel users toward leaving a specific kind of comment only.

There would be costs to this kind of change. This kind of UI design would essentially kill any sort of back-and-forth in the comments that might in some circumstances be useful to flesh out the question. It would make it much less appealing to leave a minimal "answer stub" in the comments, but I think we should be discouraging that in any case. I'm sure there are other downsides that I haven't thought of...

I've focused here solely on the idea of redesigning the comment UI under questions only. The comments under answers are used differently enough that I think they would require different treatment. Also, comments on Meta are very different as well, so UI changes probably shouldn't be made there.

Comment: Have you considered how these hypothetical changes might impact Meta, where lots of important back-and-forth can end up in comments? These changes seem like they would be either misleading or counterproductive in this context.

Comment: @DavisBroda Sure, so make the changes only on StackOverflow. (I realize that may be technically difficult, but that seems like a concern for later down the road.)

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/363051/ask-a-question-template-v1-experiment-results

Comment: Related (or possibly a dupe) on MSE: [Fixing comments in 5 minutes. Intrigued? Let's discuss](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/299195)

Comment: Cue tons of comments that all start with "Could you please provide more information about"

Comment: Another idea: comments are supposed to be ephemeral, well, why not make it so?  Any newly posted comments stick around for a limited amount of time, 2 weeks say, and then disappear.

Answer (score 1):

I am absolutely against restricting what kind of comments a user can make.

> > The asker could be shown a "clarify question" text with no option to leave their own comment.

Please never do this. From the perspective of a low-rep user this is a horrible idea.
If you need direct guidance from experienced users in how to edit  *this specific* question (not talking about reading faq and what not) back and forth comments (with the intent of improving the question) are definetly useful.
Also consider that low-rep users might not have heard of chat (or simply don't have access to it) so chat isn't a viable option for all cases.
Furthermore the only other option for dialogue would be to respond to all comments in an edit to the question itself. This might be useful for some cases ("I can't use version x because...") where it is helpful for all potential answerers. But it is way more inconvenient and awkward to hold a conversation in two different places.

Answer (score -1):

> There would be costs to this kind of change.

Setting aside the matter of how effective these changes would actually be (on that, cf. [this answer I sympathise with in a related Meta.SE discussion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/256972/242059)), I believe their cost would be too high in the specific case of Stack Overflow. They would have the side effect of also "add[ing] more friction" for writing the kinds of comment that are allowed (or tolerated) under the *status quo*. That would mean getting in the way of those users who consistently succeed in writing unobtrusive, constructive and useful comments.

> This kind of UI design would essentially kill any sort of back-and-forth in the comments that might in some circumstances be useful to flesh out the question.

Critically useful, I would say. It is worth highlighting that taking away the ability to @-ping commentators would make it unreasonably difficult to follow up on improvement suggestions if one of the involved parties is unable to respond immediately. (A possible objection here would be "why does the follow-up have to be done by you". In reply, I would point out that doing entirely away with one-on-one feedback would be suboptimal, and also a very risky strategy in lower traffic tags. Besides that, I do care about the questions I interact with.) I don't want to have my hands tied in this way.

> It would make it much less appealing to leave a minimal "answer stub" in the comments, but I think we should be discouraging that in any case.

At a minimum, we should note there is a difference between an "answer stub" that can trivially be made into an answer and what I will tentatively call a *pre-answer*: a relevant suggestion which is not quite enough for an answer -- perhaps its author is not entirely satisfied with their own solution, or unable to fully test it at the moment, or not entirely sure about all the involved details. If you have a pre-answer, is it necessary to keep it to yourself until it ripens into a fully formed answer? I would say it often isn't. Sharing it in advance through a comment gives the opportunity to the OP and to other potential answerers to build upon it, and possibly come out with a proper answer of their own.

---

On a more general note, I conjecture that the markedly objective nature of Stack Overflow Q&As means there is a rather broad range of comments that are useful in spite of not strictly fitting the primarily intended purpose of "elicit[ing] clarifications on questions" -- in other words, there are quite a few kinds of comments that won't degenerate into irrelevant digressions or flamewars. In contrast, ["good subjective"](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/09/29/good-subjective-bad-subjective/) sites such as Workplace.SE and Interpersonal.SE [tend to have even more trouble with comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/256969/242059), which makes the cost-benefit of making the moderation of comments very strict more favourable. (Though I hazard that even in those sites a number of your suggestions would be deemed as too radical.)