# My thoughts on the SO new user experience

Tags: discussion, answers, not-an-answer, post-ban, community-moderation

I guess this is being marked as a duplicate of some post asking why new users are confused about the rules. This absolutely is not about that as it's more about how the rules are administered w/o any explanation, notification or recourse - often seemingly by mods who don't really understand the subject matter or make a real attempt to understand the question (or even fix a broken answer that my answer was trying to politely point out). I wasn't trolling or being rude. The bottom line is I was trying to help correct a previous answer (which still hasn't been corrected btw). So maybe there's a better way to deal with a new user in that spot.

I just read the big "Welcoming ..." blog post everyone was talking about, and it pretty much matched my experience word for word. So you can say it's a duplicate of that if you want. Reading the comments below (and none really going the other way) it seems pretty obvious not much has changed since April. Which really bums me out as SO is such a great resource.

I don't expect this post to last much longer either way. But that's my .2c.

I have read some old posts in this forum about the attrition rate and how new users aren't always feeling valued. So as a *new user* I am just going to give you my perspective. I've been reading SO as long as it's been around, and to be honest I always felt guilty about not contributing enough. I've asked questions and gotten answers. But I don't have enough reputation to comment on posts, so my only option for contributing is answers.

I made one answer in 2014 that I guess went fine. [Then another answer a few weeks ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35252544/how-to-get-the-http-method-in-aws-lambda/52231314#52231314) that was out of context because what I was trying to do was just make a comment on the answer above mine. But again I can't comment because I don't have enough reputation. Also I can't paste screenshots like I wanted to do.

I'm not trying to rehash the particulars of that because once I made my post a separate answer I should have made the context more clear. Which I did go back and edit a couple days ago and got help in making the screenshot inline from another user.

My point is somehow that landed me in answer jail. And now I can't contribute if I wanted to. I made a post about this in the meta forum, got some very helpful advice on how to improve my answer, which I took to heart.

But also the attitude I seemed to get (and why I'm making this post after a lot of long-winded back story) was that I needed to RTFM to use SO, and that I needed to jump through some hoops to get out of 'answer jail'. Like new users have nothing better to do than go through some kind of pledge season or trial-by-fire to prove themselves to SO. The answer never seems to be that SO was wrong. There's no appeal process or even concrete understanding of how I landed in answer jail.

For me this was a very off-putting experience and very frustrating in that my actual answer was useful and trying to contribute in the spirit of SO. The user who commented negatively (which may or may not have contributed to my answer jail - I have no idea) did not really understand the question or the post I was trying to make.

I feel like maybe you guys could employ some kind of optimistic model where you give new users more of a chance until they prove otherwise. That or maybe let users with a lot of rep points vouch for new users - to get them over that first 50 points. Or check out github stars or some other ways to vouch that a user knows that they're doing w/o having to jump through all the hoops, which sometimes results in a very negative experience for the new user.

Ok that's all - again, just my perspective.

Comment: Ok I found one deleted answer. I guess it was deleted because it should have been a comment (which I can't do). https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49950249/cognito-logout-does-not-work-as-documented/52787379#52787379 Here's my answer - https://imgur.com/GOF0cv3

Btw there definitely is a typo in the official docs on this component, which the answer above mine just copied and pasted. That is what I was trying to point out. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/logout-endpoint.html

Comment: I tried to make a post about this in the AWS forums, but I wasn't allowed to post for a few hours or something. It's been a fun week for me trying to help :) I just went back and I can post now, so I notified them of the typo.

Comment: Wanting to correct a typo is good. But if you're not allowed to comment, that means you're *not allowed to comment*. That doesn't mean you post a comment as an answer. So either you wait until you *can* comment, or you simply post a competing answer that *correctly* answers the question without the typo. You don't say "Everything that guy said was right, except for this tiny thing".

Comment: 'Like new users have nothing better to do than go through some kind of pledge season or trial-by-fire to prove themselves to SO' well, guess what, skilled and experienced developers who are volunteering free time do have better things to do than continually churn through the same set of bad questions, and occasionally answers, from new accounts whose owners did not read, or did not care, about wasting anyone's time bar their own.  I'm sorry, but far too many new accounts post bad questions already without opening the floodgates any further:(

Comment: Deleted answers, score <= 0: (https://stackoverflow.com/a/52787379, https://stackoverflow.com/a/21418659, https://stackoverflow.com/a/21418601, https://stackoverflow.com/a/20483836)

Comment: @MartinJames - in both cases my answers were useful, made sense, and trying to contribute in the spirit of SO. The people who deleted or commented negatively on them spent literally no time trying to figure out what was going on.

I get that there are new accounts posting bad answers. But I also feel like negative comments or deletions that don't make sense could also be a problem. And that never seems to be addressed. It seems to be always and only the new user's fault.

Comment: @NicolBolas - maybe the problem is in not allowing a new user to comment. What is the rationale behind that?

Comment: *That or maybe let users with a lot of rep points vouch for new users...* This doesn't make sense. How can anyone promise that a person who's ever used the site before knows how to use the site properly? *Or check out github stars or some other ways to vouch that a user knows that they're doing...* But using GitHub doesn't mean you know how to use Stack Overflow. The two sites are completely different: one's a code repository and the other is a Q&A site.

Comment: *What is the rationale behind that?* Comments can only be deleted by diamond mods so they don't want spammers to have access to the comments section. 50 reputation points = we trust that you aren't here just to spam the site.

Comment: @BSMP - I comment on a ton of other sites like github issues and programmer forums with none of these problems. No one restricts me from posting screenshots or only making certain kinds of answers/comments. I've read stack overflow since its inception. I've been a developer, lead dev and then architect for 20 years. I know how to write a well-formed answer. Literally every issue I've had with this site is because i wanted to comment but was only allowed to post an answer. So I posted an answer with something snarky to that effect and then got put in answer jail.

Comment: @BSMP The only way I can get reputation points apparently is to post answers, which I can't do anymore. Can you see how SO is creating barriers to entry? You should want people to contribute imo, not make it harder for them.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/373158/what-does-our-long-term-community-need-what-does-our-long-term-community-need-t

https://imgur.com/BbObcfO

Maybe there is a reason for this other than the new users being in the wrong.

Comment: Is there some incentive in place for these people who are deleting or making negative comments on answers? They really don't seem to be digging to hard to figure out what's going on.

It seems much easier for a new user to comment and add something to an existing answer, vs. submit their own answer. Maybe it shouldn't be so hard to get privileges to comment.

Comment: _"I've been a developer, lead dev and then architect for 20 years. I know how to write a well-formed answer."_ I'm sure you are an excellent professional. But shouldn't your experience here have taught you that maybe you do not fully grasp how to write answers that are considered useful within the confines of this site? Saying that you _do_ know, despite your results so far, looks slightly misguided, IMO.

Comment: My answers were useful in the context of comments. I got an answer deleted and another negatively commented because I posted an answer when I wasn't allowed to post a comment.

I know I'm being kind of a jerk on this and I apologize. It's because I've gotten so much use out of SO over the years. I love SO. But I feel like it's falling down somewhat here. What I have experienced when trying to contribute is very frustrating and not encouraging to me. I don't feel like either of my answers were even considered for their actual content. Shouldn't that be the most important thing?

Comment: Getting enough rep to comment, if you are as committed as you say you are to contribute, is **extremely** easy. If instead of spending all this time complaining about how the site should work, you used the same energy to write one good answer (which you can't right now, because you flaunted the rules) or maybe a few edits to improve existing posts, you'd be able to post comments without issue.

Comment: So edits are my only option right now? Ok. I'll try that.

Comment: Your options to gain enough rep to comment right now are: contribute with good edits, contribute with good questions, wait a couple of months and contribute with a good answer.

Comment: Or I could keep reading SO but not contributing, which is what many posts I've read in the meta forum are fretting about, and what I will almost certainly do after taking the temperature of how the regs on this site feel about new users. Maybe I'll send people a message if I think I can help them.

Comment: So you say you want to "contribute", but are completely unwilling to do the least effort to contribute in a way the site needs and appreciate. I get it.

Comment: @yivi the bottom line is - [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51517387/3084991) this incorrect answer is still up. I tried to point out that the poster is propagating an obvious typo in the AWS docs. But apparently I have no mechanism to do so. Furthermore I was punished for trying to "flaunt the rules" in an effort to very politely point out that I think the answer is propagating an obvious typo - which will only confuse SO users searching for the correct answer (including me at the time).

Do we care about getting the answer right?

Comment: You have the most obvious mechanism to do so: **suggest an edit**. That would work both to correct the mistake, and help you in your way to earn the necessary rep to post comments in the future. No idea why you are so determined to go against the grain instead of learning to use the existing tools.

Comment: Sorry but editing other people's posts is not obvious at all to me. I know I should RTFM. But maybe there a kinder, gentler approach - like how wikipedia deals with new users that could work here instead of just deleting someone's answer (which I didn't even realize happened).

FYI I suggested an edit.

Comment: I also made a post in the AWS forums about this for them to fix their docs. https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=292034&tstart=0

Comment: 'maybe there a kinder, gentler approach' well, how does that work for you with, say 'compiler/linker errors?   No matter how obvious it is that variable X should be external, the linker still keeps issuing 'unresolved' errors until you fix the linkage to follow the rules.   Comments and answers are differently typed sets and are, in general, not assignable or castable.  I'm very surprised that, as a software professional, you don't understand rules.

Comment: Maybe instead of just deleting my answer I could have gotten some feedback on what I did wrong. And maybe the mod who deleted my answer could have shown some concern over correcting the wrong answer that I was trying to point out. Isn't getting answers right the ultimate point here? Or is it following rules? But by all means please attack my programming abilities.

Comment: @MattS I do not know, or care about your programming abilities.   I don't know you at all, so that's pretty obvious.  I am, howver, baffled by users who can accept that languages, compilers, linkers etc. have rules that cannot be broken, but SO rules can be just ignored when they are inconvenient:(

Comment: 'I could have gotten some feedback on what I did wrong' well ,maybe.  Some users do give feedback, (though that often results in street brawls).  There is no mechanism for enforcing feedback, and I doubt that any such mechanism is workable.  I suppose that some system for requesting additional information on votes/closures/deletions could be implemented, but I doubt that it would be popular - it would be very expensive since the requester would effectively be seeking to hire skilled and experienced developers.

Comment: Well to use your compiler analogy - when you break the compiler rules, it gives you useful feedback so you can correct your mistake. It doesn't just delete your code and forbid you from using the compiler again.

Comment: *I've read stack overflow since its inception. I've been a developer, lead dev and then architect for 20 years.* I'm not disputing that. I'm saying that it doesn't mean you know all of Stack Overflow's rules. Currently, the only way to prove that you can and will use the site properly is to earn reputation. If you have another way for users to prove themselves that isn't easily exploited by spammers, that would be great. But GitHub usage won't work.

Comment: @MattS 'It doesn't just delete your code and forbid you from using the compiler again' true, but then again, neither does SO.  To get to the ban/suspension stage,, you have to ignore the rules/poliies that you agreed that you read when opening your account and also ignore the warning emails that highligted you poor Q/A record and yet again provided helpful links.  It's not easy to get Q/A banned  - you have to put in some effort to ask multiple bad questions/answers and ignore several warnings;)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Content, rules, and perceptions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366956/content-rules-and-perceptions)

Comment: see also: [Can we make it more obvious to new users that downvotes on the main site are not insults and in fact can help them help themselves?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/366889/839601)

Answer (score 12):

> I feel like maybe you guys could employ some kind of optimistic model where you give new users more of a chance until they prove otherwise.

We do.  We let *anyone* post answers to (almost) *anything*, right off the bat.  You don't need to earn the right to post answers, you are given it freely.  You intentionally abused it by knowingly posting numerous answers that *you know* were not supposed to be posted as answers.  As such, you lost the *privilege* of being able to answer due to your behavior.

SO doesn't really need to give you any ability to regain it at all, but they have done so because they realize people can learn from their mistakes (even after making the same mistake *numerous* times, despite the various warnings, as you have done).  As such, you're able to earn the privilege of answering back.  You *do* have that appeal process.  It's not trivial.  That's because what you did to lose the privilege wasn't trivial.  If being able to answer is important to you, then it'll be worth the effort it takes to regain that privilege.  If you think that SO was wrong to think that you aren't able to follow the rules, then *show us*, rather than claiming that you're going to be a good contributor that follows the rules while your actual actions show otherwise.

It's also worth taking a second to point out that you're not a "new user", as your title is claiming you are.  You've been around for years, and had numerous interactions with the site over that time.  The problem wasn't even that you didn't know what was expected of you.  Due to your participation over that time you *did* know what was expected of you, and simply *choose* to violate the rules.

> the rules are administered w/o any explanation, notification or recourse

But you understood the rules before you broke them.  You *knew* you were breaking the rules.  Thus, clearly the rules *were* explained to you.  How else would you have known you shouldn't do what you were doing?

Additionally, you *did* see warnings when posting answers that you were doing things wrong and that previous answers of yours were deleted, and that you need to correct the behavior.  You were notified that you were doing something wrong, and choose to continue doing that same behavior anyway.

Finally, you *do* have a recourse. You're just unwilling to take the time to do what you need to do to earn back the privilege to answer.  That you find the recourse *too much work* for you doesn't mean you don't have one.

Comment: Sometimes the truth can be unwelcoming ...

Comment: FWIW I had no idea how seriously you guys take the rules here. I was trying to help correct a previous answer in the only way I knew how. 

The bottom line is my answer was in the spirit of getting correct information into the thread (which still hasn't been corrected btw). If I was trolling or being rude then I could see going to answer jail. But maybe in a situation like this there is a way to let the user know what they did wrong and help them to fix it - instead of just delete the answer, which also revokes privileges to answer again. I feel like there has to be a better way.

Comment: @MattS If you were just trolling the consequences would have been much more severe, and you wouldn't have had nearly as many warnings.  You had *numerous* changes to correct your behavior, and warnings not to continue engaging in the behavior, which you *repeatedly* ignored.  It took you being banned from answering to get you to stop doing something you knew you shouldn't have done.  That you didn't stop short of that showed it to actually be a necessary step.

Comment: What are you talking about? I got no warnings, no notifications and I had no idea why I was banned from answering. Only after making posts in the meta forum did I start searching around and found the deleted answers tab. Before that I thought it was because of my screenshot answer where the mod clearly had no idea what I was trying to show. I still have no idea if that's why, since SO specifically does not tell you what you did wrong. 

And whew thank goodness I still get to keep this 17 rep account in answer jail. Glad I didn't lose that to "more severe consequences". o_O

Comment: Where exactly was I supposed to be seeing these notifications? There's nothing in my inbox. I get emails from SO every time someone replies to this thread - but I got none for my deleted answer. Here's a screenshot of my answers: https://imgur.com/9Muq6wx

The only way to even see that there deleted answers, is to click the Answers header. I'm surprised I even found it at all. https://imgur.com/BM0Pzup

Comment: Here is the all the information given on my deleted post: "deleted by greg-449, Flexo♦ Oct 13 at 8:45
Why was your post deleted? See the help center." FYI - greg-449 is a Fortran developer with 80k points who apparently doesn't know what an obvious typo in the protocol of a URL looks like. Looks like my edit to fix the obvious typo in logout_uri was rejected: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51517387/3084991 Rules must be followed. Getting answers right - not so important apparently.

Comment: @MattS When posting an answer you should be getting a warning if you're close to being banned.

Comment: The only notification I got was the next time I tried to post an answer and it wouldn't let me. That was literally the first time i realized I had done something wrong. I assumed it was because of my answer with a screenshot that one user commented negatively on. But really I had no idea. I got no notification from the deleted answer and as you can see there is no information there on why it was deleted.

Comment: Also I guess you aren't going to address the wrong answer that is still up there confusing people (like me originally)? I feel like the culture here has forgotten the original purpose of the site, and moved on to something completely different. Some googling has confirmed that I am in a lot of company with that opinion. This has been the worst initial community experience I've ever had on the web. I'm just going to use SO in read-only from now on like most people - which I get seems to be what a lot of long time users want.

Comment: @MattS There are lots of wrong answers on the site.  You can either earn the trust of the site in order to have more sophisticated tools for dealing with them, like comments and downvotes (which have *very* low bars), or you can post your own, better, answers, that don't have whatever problems you feel are an issue.  You want to be trusted to have a lot of control over other people's content, and yet your actions all demonstrate that you're *not* trustworthy.  Both your complete inability to provide valuable content to earn the privileges, and your repeated violation of the rules.

Comment: @MattS The rules are not arbitrary.  They're not there "just because".  They're there because considerable time and effort has gone into determining what produces the highest quality content in the end.  The rules that exist here, many of which don't exist on other similar sites, are the *reason* for much of the useful content here.