# Can we be more welcoming by managing expectations?

Tags: discussion, new-users, welcoming

I've just cleared the First Posts review queue. *Only one* of the questions I could assess did not merit a vote-to-close or a VLQ flag. How "welcome" do you suppose those newcomers feel?

We already know that a sizeable fraction of new users perceive down-votes and votes-to-close as unwelcoming. Jaydles in [his infamous "welcoming" blog](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366665/does-stack-exchange-really-want-to-conflate-newbies-with-women-people-of-color) specifically referred to them. If 90% of them take it in their stride and improve, what about the remaining 10%? And if only 1% of new users who get a VTC or VLQ flag post a critical tweet, how worried will SE be that we are *not welcoming enough*?

There is an infamous "alt-right" site named [Breitbart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breitbart_News). I'm very left wing. But I've *never* felt unwelcome on one of its associated fora or websites. Yes, **never**. Why? Because *I've never gone there*. I already *know* that if I was to honestly start posting on one of those fora, I would be picking a fight, and I've decided to leave fighting that kind of vile-and-stupid to others.

**Feeling** unwelcome is an emotional response, not an intellectual assessment of a theoretical. I do not, and have never had, an emotion of rejection as a result of interaction with Breitbart. It *really is* accurate to say that it *has not made me feel unwelcome*.

Breitbart's "reputation" precedes it. But imagine it did not. Imagine I'd heard it was a something like an SE [politics](https://politics.stackexchange.com/) site and started making left-wing slanted posts. The fire-hose of abuse and overwhelmingly right-wing replies would certainly make me feel *unwelcome*.

[Yes, I know, some SE posts have been unwelcoming. Some even going so far as to be racist or sexist. I still do not believe that the *small fraction* of bad content on SO can explain the *perception* that SO is particularly unwelcoming].

Is the problem with people *complaining* about SO being unwelcoming *mostly* due to many programmers being aware of SO, even if they do not use it, but most of them misunderstanding what SO is about, so when they post their vague off-topic questions, [they get a rude shock](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366956/content-rules-and-perceptions)?

Could the *perception* that SO is unwelcoming be improved by better communicating to those who do *not* (yet) use it what  SO is? So if/when they use it, they have a better idea of what our expectations are.

That is, manage their expectations, by being off-putting to the lazy, unenthusiastic and unprofessional? Even [*before* they try to ask their first question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/367092/changing-new-users-expectations-of-this-site-before-they-ask-their-question)? I think it might be *too late* at the point when they click on the "Ask Question" button, *even if* that actually takes them to a tutorial or [test](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266361/the-good-the-bad-the-ugly). At that point they want an answer to *their* question, and attempts at educating them (as has been pointed out many times) will been treated as annoyances to be clicked through with minimum attention.

I'm not really suggesting we need more technical measures (although they might help) to [educate them in what is expected of them](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/285903/170084). I'm suggesting more about messages, signage and (dare I say it) marketing. Consider the SO homepage that a new user lands on at https://stackoverflow.com/. Near the top it says "Top Questions" and has the "Ask Question" button. There is **no indication at all** that SO is a site for *professional and enthusiast programmers*. None that it is unsuitable for novices who are learning to program. It appears that *any* question about programming should be acceptable.

Managing expectations would have a benefit in addition to reducing the number of new users who feel unwelcome. It would take the sting out of unfair criticisms made of SO in other fora. Imagine someone were to tweet "I'm unhappy that SO caters only for enthusiast and professional programmers, because I want it to cater to lazy beginners like myself". How much sympathy would they get?

Comment: How is being "welcome" related to closing questions?

Comment: Are you sure people who _would_ find SO off-putting after managing their expectations as you put it.. will _not_ say its unwelcoming in a tweet or any other form? I am not entirely sure your proposal helps reduce negative perception. As you put it, you still find Breitbart unwelcoming

Comment: ...Ok, do you have any suggestions to more clearly communicate that which questions are on-topic (apart from showing them the /ask/advice page before they ask the first question, having a "How to ask" banner to the right of the screen while they're typing, and (at some point in the future) have /ask/wizard)

Comment: @Raedwald I'd imagine a lot, because number of "lazy beginners" are much more than number of "professional programmers". (?)

Comment: _How much sympathy would they get?_ I would say it depends. You also need to remember that Twitter has its problems with echo chambers. I do get your point though. The purpose of SO can be made clearer and it would reduce the number of low quality/off topic stuff

Comment: *Outsider's perspective:* I love SO. I always find myself coming back whenever I run into a problem because it's almost guaranteed that I'll find a solution to my problem based on the wealth of knowledge here. The catch is that in order for a good answer to exist, a good question must exist first. I understand the push to make new users feel welcome but I don't agree that it is more important than being blunt about what's a good question and what is not in order to maintain quality. If new users can't get over the fact that they got downvoted, well, they need life lessons... not SO lessons.

Comment: @Ihazkode Although some people are trying to be more welcoming, they've never said that keeping high quality questions are less important. I don't see how your comment is relevant.

Comment: I think a core problem that it is just not very obvious where else they could go to get help.  An unfortunate side-effect of SO's early success is that it pretty effectively killed off forum support.  The hordes released by the first [welcoming] campaign in 2012 and the removal of effective moderation tools in 2013 did in turn kill SO.  .  Users will find an alternative, eventually, maybe there's a bright future ahead for forums and mailing lists again.  Not sure if that is not already happening, I don't visit Breitbart either.

Comment: @HansPassant Perhaps an SE site for Learning to Program? Suggestions like that have been shot down before, but perhaps it needs re-examination?

Comment: I don't think it's in SE's mandate to cater to every single audience.  If you need to learn how to program, the process is not conducive to the QA format, so it doesn't really fall in the scope.  It needs far too much back and forth, trial and error to achieve that basic knowledge.  We can build on it from there, but providing that base needs to happen elsewhere.

Comment: How can you say you don't feel unwelcome at a site when you have never visited it and state that posting on it would end up starting a fight?

Comment: @user202729 I've seen people link to the blog post while complaining about downvotes on their question. It's not far-fetched to imagine people feeling unwelcome because their question gets closed.

Comment: The fact that you give an example of a site that you have no experience with and only know of from its reputation isn't very helpful for your argument

Comment: @Stijn Then it's not our fault and we don't *have* to do anything. SE may want to do something however.

Comment: I believe SE is making efforts in this direction, like the perpetually-pending “ask a question wizard”. I also am a little cynical about when or even if we’ll ever see it. SO has painted itself into a corner. As a business, they need new users to grow, but the vast majority of potential users can’t live up to the standards you observe in this post. They have a dilemma: growth and sustainability, or quality and reputation? Yahoo Answers! or death?

Comment: @HansPassant I suggest we send them to [AskQuestions.Tech](https://www.askquestions.tech/), the self-proclaimed *inclusive tech community to ask and answer technical questions*.

Comment: @Stijn I think sending people other places just reinforces a problematic misperception I’d rather challenge than subsidize. That misperception is that SE is or should be the “root” of a given user’s search tree. In fact it should be a “leaf”, and one should only post when they are already aware of what SE is and that it is the *right place to ask*. If the answer is “go to this other site”, it’s not the right place to ask.

Comment: As a counter example, I don't feel welcome at ServerFault, because I'm not a [professional server administrator](https://meta.serverfault.com/questions/1760/server-fault-is-for-system-administrators-in-a-professional-capacity). I would say that the site is unwelcoming to me, whether or not I go to there.

Comment: @Houseman but isn't the case of you feeling unwelcomed on you? Meaning, the reason you don't feel welcome is because you don't have the knowledge / aren't a professional server administrator so surely if *you* want to feel welcomed, you should well... become one? To put it another way, let's say I'm having a party and I've invited a bunch of friends and you (a complete stranger) happen to walk past and want to join in, if I say '*Sorry, only people who are invited or at the very least know me are invited.*' am I now in danger of being unwelcoming?

Comment: Please keep in mind that the person who did the First Posts review before you could be a cherry-picker, only reviewing good posts and leaving the rotten ones for someone else. This happens now and then.

Comment: @Lundin However, previous times I have cleared the queue it has also been full of garbage.

Comment: @Script47 You are correct, it is "on me". However, If I go to twitter and say "I'm not welcome", would it make a difference? I suppose I would have to intentionally leave out the "because I'm not a professional server administrator" part, so that people would be more inclined to be sympathetic, but disingenuous twitter users would probably do that too.

Comment: @Raedwald '*Some even going so far as to be racist or sexist.*' - In my 5 years and 7 months on this site, I've still yet to come across a racist or sexist post. Are you just repeating the claims or have you actually come across any? If so, how frequently do you come across them?

Comment: @Houseman '*. However, If I go to twitter and say "I'm not welcome", would it make a difference?*' - I'm guessing you must have missed the [HNQ fiasco](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/316934/revisiting-the-hot-network-questions-feature-what-are-our-shared-goals-for-ha) (and related [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/317087/se-needs-a-better-social-media-policy-and-could-us-experienced-users-get-a-litt)) that all happened due to Twitter. Don't underestimate the amount of disingenuous people who cause issues for others by echoing unfounded sentiments to push an agenda.

Comment: @Script47 Nope, I'm intimately familiar with it. My point is that if I "feel unwelcome", regardless of why, it can still be complained about on twitter

Comment: @Houseman so your point is "anyone can still decide to feel unwelcome and go on Twitter to complain"... does it basically mean "you can't please everyone, stop trying"? Cause that's how I read it...

Comment: I understood it as how @Patrice just interpreted it as and if that is your intention then we agree on the what should happen.

Comment: @Patrice I'm just giving a counter-point, that, personally, I feel unwelcome in places where I do not belong, and where I'm not invited. That's all

Comment: @Houseman but that was my original point, isn't it obvious that you'd feel uncomfortable (not unwelcomed, personally) in places that you do not belong? So the next logical question is why would you even go to those place? Unless you get kicks out of feeling like that I don't see why you'd even go there. Going back to your example of ServerFault, I, by no means am an expert in regards to servers / workings, hence, to my knowledge, I don't have account as part of that site, however I still read interesting posts from there and get help from there, I just don't get involved in their meta or main.

Comment: @Script47 I understand and see your logic. To me, though, this wouldn't solve the problem of "feeling unwelcome", as I'd still feel "not welcome" in a place like server fault, even if it were clear that I don't belong there. Maybe I'll put this in an answer

Comment: @Script47 "In my 5 years and 7 months on this site, I've still yet to come across a racist or sexist post." I see more on meta than on main.  You also end up seeing more of it when you hit 10k as you're able to see deleted post years after they've been deleted for being abusive, rather than needing to see them in the few second/minute window that they have before they get deleted.  People who focus more on the curation site of things, rather than simply posting questions/answers, will also naturally come across more of said content.  But content like this is *very* rare.

Comment: @Servy fair enough, mine was a purely anecdotal point and I guess people will have different experiences but naturally, these sort of trash posts are expected (because of the size of the audience and the trollish nature of people on the Internet) but to try argue that there is a intrinsic issue with SO that makes it unwelcoming to minorities, females, or even new beginners is simply put, wrong. Again, this is based on my experiences as I don't think we can factually determine something like this.

Comment: @Script47 Sure, I'm not saying that SO has a problem with offensive content.  I'm saying that some amount of it being posed is inevitable, ans SO is no exception; it's how it's handled that affects the experience of everyday users.  SO is quick to delete and/or hide said content *very* quickly, so most people never, or rarely, see it.  It's better at doing this than most sites (or comparable size) on the internet.  I'm just pointing out that the reason you're not seeing offensive content isn't because it's not there, it's because people in the community do a good job of removing it quickly.

Comment: _"It really is accurate to say that it [Breitbart] has not made me feel unwelcome."_. Nonsense. It may be factually true, but it is not accurate at all. You may as well claim _"It really is accurate to say that the King of Sweden has not made me feel unwelcome."_. Factually true, but so what? It is a completely meaningless approach for supporting your argument.

Comment: @Servy absolutely, you are correct on all counts there, but that's where my contention is, where did this "unwelcoming" stuff first begin from? It wasn't the blog, because people mentioned it before that. Is merely a small number of people who have experienced these issues? That's why I posted my anecdotal point that in my time I've not seen any of that stuff, I've definitely seen my fair of rude / sweary / grossly offensive content (just the other day I came across a comment comparing SO curators to Nazis) but none specifically sexist or racist. 1/2

Comment: I absolutely agree though, SO's curators / janitors / whatever you want to call them are probably the best that I've seen. Yet, people still complain. 2/2

Comment: @Script47 The "unwelcoming" comes from the fact that SO is designed to be a place with high quality standards.  It was *designed* to be a place that didn't welcome low quality content, the way other sites previously did (and mostly still do).  It has never come from content that's actually rude or offensive.

Comment: @Servy again, I completely agree with you and therefore it goes back to my original comment [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/377101/be-more-welcoming-by-managing-expectations#comment650397_377101) to the OP. People keep repeating racism and sexism but has anyone been able to back this up with factual evidence that SO by nature treats non-whites or women badly?The only reason I ask is the more people keep repeating unfounded comments it makes it seem as though they are in fact true so when people do get VTCed or down-voted, they don't think they made the mistake but they go 1/2.

Comment: with the assumption that they were wronged and if by chance they fall under an "ism" or "cism" then they claim that. My stance has always been that SO should've come out it front of the claims head on and challenged them and said that prove our community has a "problem" with racism or sexism.

Comment: why do votes on a question need to be public in the first place?

Comment: @isaace considering votes are supposed to help other users decide which content is valuable and which isn't.... why would they ever **not** be public?

Comment: because it makes people feel unwelcoming and in many cases, just because a question in downvoted isn't an indicator that the content is not valuable.

Comment: a small like and dislike flag would be a lot less unwelcoming than a big number on display. I mean, I am not a UX person, but I am sure it can be designed in a way that less users will feel unwelcoming. I am not talking about myself. I'm ok here.

Comment: @isaace but..... isn't "downvoting" an indication of the quality (or lack thereof) of the content it's on? So it very usually means "if it's downvoted, it's an indicator that the content isn't valuable". By at least the person who voted, it is. And while a "like" or "dislike" flag would be smaller than a number, you lose: 1) the granularity (a -20 question isn't **simply** "dislike").  And 2) by using the words "like" and "dislike", it becomes way easier to take it personally. I didn't downvote your post because I thought it didn't meet our standards. I "disliked" it....

Comment: @isaace Sure, downvotes make people feel unwelcome.  You know what makes me feel unwelcome?  No effort questions from users who treat us as a help desk, without making any effort to try to solve their own problems, telling us to shut up and just answer their question.  It's all a matter of perspective.

Comment: maybe you feel taken advantage of(really no one is forcing you to answer those type of questions) but not unwelcome.

Comment: @isaace no... the very site is making these changes and asking us to change our ways, implying that a lot of what we used to do is "unwelcoming" and "not nice". That is the site very clearly telling us our actions aren't helpful anymore. *We aren't welcome in our own community anymore*. Stack would prefer all inclusiveness and niceness from everyone present, without regards for quality.

Comment: @isaace That's a classic argument used in their defense.  To which I counter with, "Understand what SO is all about."  Low quality content does not belong.  We're not forced to answer it.  Neither are we forced to allow it to reside here, if it doesn't fit with our goal.

Comment: so you feel unwelcome because SO is asking you to be more welcoming, ok I can hear that.

Comment: @isaace nah, it's a bit more complex than that. We *disagree* about the current stance of "welcoming" vs "unwelcoming". But SO made it clear they will not listen and just go ahead and steamroll changes. I am all for being welcoming, don't get me wrong. In the **right** way. So are most of the veteran users. There is definitely a dichotomy between veterans and non-veterans that shows. The veteran's aren't saying "we don't want to be welcoming". The veterans are saying "we are as welcoming as we've always been. What gives?"

Comment: I think stackoverflow is by far the least welcoming site I have ever been to. People seems very arrogant and I try to make fewest posts possible in order to avoid being harassed and not only that... people here apparently even expect you to thank them for harassing you as well. Yes i appericiate help but i dont need to be told how stupid i am. One of the most usefull sites, but definitely im my experience the most unwelcoming site by far.....Now im not usually receiving downvotes anymore and i dont have to read how stupid i am anymore but as a beginner its like a complete bully website

Comment: Speaking of users not understanding what SO is about and refusing to listen...

Comment: One problem is that [Ask] is broken.  It does not prepare users for the various standards which have evolved.  Things like pictures of code, compleat error messages, the code which produces the error, notes on what is too broad (and how to fix it), how to freaking search the 20,000,000 answers already here, that it is not a tutorial site.  maybe even a note on what a DV means.  Secondly, there is no requirement to read anything ever to be able to continue posting.  The core problem is that SE has become an absentee  landlord - they only pop up now and then to weep about some new initiative

Comment: @exceed  - you have a total of 2 out of 21 posts with 3 total DVs so unless you had another account, you *never* got many DVs - and the 2 with DVs looked deserved as OT.  If 3 DVs on 2 posts is cruelty, perhaps I could introduce you to April W's site?

Comment: Let's see. '*I think stackoverflow is by far the least welcoming site I have ever been to.*' and what makes so "unwelcoming" can you give some experiences and if possible posts of yours which attracted these people? '*People seems very arrogant*', again, can we have some examples? From my experiences trying to enforce rules is classed as being arrogant. '*in order to avoid being harassed*', If you have ever been harassed on the site, report it to the mods and they'll deal with it, swiftly. '*i dont need to be told how stupid i am*', once again, report and it will be dealt with... 1/2

Comment: don't bury your head in the sand (by not doing anything to report the responsible party) and expect to change to occur. '*but as a beginner its like a complete bully website*', once again, a site enforcing its rules is not bullying. In fact, it is quite telling on the asker when they refuse to acknowledge issues with themselves and point the blame elsewhere, always. Like I mentioned earlier, people keep repeating this stuff, but that doesn't prove a single thing, bring some evidence to the table. Help us help you make the community even better.

Comment: No doubt SO has a steep learning curve and I, myself, have been down-voted to oblivion and stopped using the site (on another account) but the truth is, I never saw it as an SO problem. I understood that I had to get and honestly, even poor questions on SO (not terrible but poor) get answers and truthfully, if you post such a poor question then don't expect to get praise and for things to get sugar coated. 'tis the internet after all.

Comment: @Stijn redirecting people to askquestions.tech is probably not going to work, that site had its last question 22d ago and is averaging only a couple of questions a month. I don't think redirecting people there would be considered a good faith effort. Honestly part of the problem is that SE hasn't got much in terms of competition. If you look for an effectual way to find a solution to your unanswered question, it's SE or the highway. Forum support has been largely abandoned, product forums redirect to SE instead now. There isn't an alternative.

Comment: AskQuestions.tech is a beautiful, terrible example of what Stack Overflow would look like if we didn't stand against the darkness of zero effort.

Comment: @IanKemp I just visited and they get a few Qs a month. On the technical questions, you mostly see zero answers, crickets. On the interpersonal problems, you see several answers suggesting approaches. I think this is a manifest result of the market that site targets and advertises to.

Comment: I joined to upvote a question (and its answers) that had several excellent answers that saved me a lot of time. And then I spotted a question I could answer while searching for an answer to a different problem I had. I haven't had to ask a question (other than a few comments for clarification) because it's been asked or by the time I've explored the problem enough to formulate a good question, I've answered it. I expect most C++ questions to be closed. Until the next mega standard update comes in and upsets the C++ apple cart, there aren't that many new C++ questions left to be asked.

Comment: The answer to this is obviously yes and something we have moved past years ago; this post is a little puzzling as we have seen many efforts over recent months (and also years) to fix the issue that you... propose might be an issue.

Comment: @TylerH "this post is a little puzzling as we have seen many efforts over recent months". I've seen efforts directed at the problem of "being unwelcoming", but not at managing expectations *before* someone tries to ask a question.

Comment: @Raedwald It's not possible to do that. Users come to websites, not the other way around.

Comment: Lazy beginners are enthusiasts. The hardest part of starting out is figuring out what you don't know, including not knowing that you need to figure out what you don't know. Can we just admit that learning to program is difficult and people generally start out being garbage at it?

Comment: @Steve Being "garbage" at developing software is not a problem at all, there a literally millions of questions from users who have no idea what they are doing. A huge part of the problem is that many people (not just the newcomers) are writing lazy, un-researched posts and then get upset when they get downvoted/told-off/closed/banned.

Comment: @DavidG you assume they're un-researched. What's probably happening is that they're just poorly researched because these people don't have the ability to research their problem to a satisfactory degree. I sure as hell didn't when I first started. Gotta keep in mind that you can't comment on other peoples posts to ask questions until you have 25 rep too. That basically means that if you're using windows when the accepted questions addressing your problems are using linux but never explicitly state it you have to ask a question to get clarification for your case. Just an example to highlight

Comment: @DavidG that particular issue with how SO goes about gate keeping. As a beginner you could also just not understand something else about the answer and be forced to either ask a new question or leave unsatisfied after making an account probably for the sole purpose of leaving a comment when you can't. I also didn't know how write MVC when I first started. At another point someone accused me of asking a bad question because my question was in there words "word vomit with some code" which is pretty sad cause it was pretty clearly written with an explanation of my goals and an MVC. I also got

Comment: @DavidG absolutely destroyed by the meta-effect. I've been here around 3 years and my reputation won't reach 200 this decade because of the enormous hole I ended up digging simply by asking for help repeatedly. This site just doesn't work when you're not good at programming.

Comment: @Steve Yes, I'm sure you have anecdotal evidence that you were treated badly, but I would posit that the vast majority of people who post that *have* done the research and *have* spent more than 3 seconds writing their question are not treated badly. New users think that downvotes and comments explaining why their question is not answerable are a slap in the face because they don't understand how the site works.

Comment: @Steve PS You've asked 12 questions, 1 has zero score and the rest are in the negative. Have you considered that you are doing something wrong rather than blaming the site?

Comment: @DavidG What you're doing is part of the problem. SO management has even admitted that the site being unwelcoming is a problem and you're still not listening to what people are telling about how the site does not work well enough for beginners. You're still assuming that people aren't trying, and you're still just writing off criticism. Trying looking at "How do I install pip" or "how do I install x with pip" type questions or over a thousand upvotes. Listen to what people are telling you about the site instead of just brushing it off because you don't believe someone could be that unskilled.

Comment: @DavidG yeah I have... Thought that was obvious when I said it got worse after I asked for help on meta. Check my activities on other Stack Exchange sites. It's literally just SO.

Comment: @DavidG We've been [over this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/375766/1197934) with him multiple times. They continue to equate curation with being welcoming.  It's not worth it to continue.  Best to just disengage.

Comment: On a sad note, this question has been just removed from the Hot Meta Posts side panel.

Comment: @Steve This site doesn't work well for beginners? It is **not a beginners site**.

Comment: @Raedwald Stack Overflow management disagrees. Their position is and as far as I can tell has been that SO is for everyone who codes.

Comment: @Steve If SO management believes that, then they can change the system to ensure that happens.  It has not, ergo, that seems to be false.  Indeed, we have much proof to the contrary.  What do *you* have?

Comment: @fbueckert SO management does believe this and they are trying to change the system to ensure that it's more user friendly. Take the recent code of conduct change and the be nice policy.

Comment: @Steve And not a single one of those has anything to do with SO being for everyone who codes.  Again, what *proof* do you have that SE management wants to allow anything and everything?  User friendliness does not mean open to all; that just means the system provides a decent experience.

Comment: @fbueckert I never said they wanted to ally anything and everything. I said that anyone was welcome here. If you read any of the business regarding the be nice policy you would understand that the policy was implemented specifically to make stack overflow more welcoming. You would also see the effort being expended by Management to follow up on this repeatedly. You'd also see this happening other places like the question wizard SO implemented specifically to help new users ask better questions. Honestly, at this point, if you don't get the message it's because your head is in the sand.

Comment: @Steve That management effort is to retain more users, yes.  But that has literally **nothing** to do with SO being open to everyone who codes.  There is a base level of quality that must be met.  What, *specifically*, do you have that says management wants to remove that base?  The ask question wizard will actually *prevent* more questions from being asked, by setting expectations that it's not a good question.  The better experience is specifically to ensure our level of quality is met, so curators are less inundated.

Comment: @fbueckert What are you doing? Stop rephrasing my point to fit your purposes. At this point, we've gone back and forth enough for you to know me personally. What are you doing?

Comment: I'm pointing out the flawed perspective you have, by challenging your viewpoint.  You've stated that SE management wants to make SO open to everyone who codes, multiple times.  I want to see the proof of that.  If your proof consists of the tired CoC and be nice policy, well, you don't understand them as well as you think.

Comment: @fbueckert They don't want to remove quality. They want it to be more welcoming to everyone. That's what I said the first time. That's what I'm going to say literally every time. Look at the who SO says it's for. Professionals and Enthusiasts. What do you think qualifies as an enthusiast? Literally anyone interested qualifies. The definition of enthusiast is anyone who's highly interested. Doesn't mean they're knowledgeable. Just means they're interested.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184435/discussion-between-fbueckert-and-steve).

Comment: If you think Breitbart is alt-right, you're missing out on the true alt-right stuff. Please don't bring up politics when making a point. It's needlessly distracting, and this is an international site - making us international visitors feel somewhat out of touch.

Comment: @Steve "Look at the who SO says it's for. Professionals and Enthusiasts." - You quote incorrectly and out of context. That's "professional and enthusiast **programmers** - "programmers" meaning a certain amount of foreknowledge and experience is present.

Comment: @CindyMeister https://www.dictionary.com/browse/programmer programmer doesn't mean good at programming, knowledgeable about programming, or experience at programming. Programmer means one who programs. You can be an enthusiast programmer, be just starting out, and be complete garbage at programming. SO is meant for enthusiast programmers too so it follows that SO is also for beginners who don't know anything.

Comment: @Steve Your pedantry here is not helpful. If I were to say "Steve is a brain surgeon", that would be taken to mean that Steve in fact had some ability at brain surgery.

Comment: At the end of the day, being a programmer/brain surgeon/data analyst/whathaveyou requires a minimum level of skill.  I can myself an enthusiast mechanic, and that carries the implication I have a higher level of skill than the average joe, which I don't have, therefore that's false.  Just because you *want* to be a programmer doesn't automatically mean you are one.

Comment: @Raedwald Being bad at programming is some ability at programming. Like it or not "hello world" and actively finding new ways to do new and more things in programming makes you an enthusiast. That would mean that Stack Overflow is also for you to use.

Comment: @fbueckert being able to point to stuff on a car would be a higher level of skill than the average joe. I think you're greatly overestimating how much an skill an average person has outside of their domain.

Comment: @Steve That means you can identify it.  Which is *entirely different* from knowing how to fix it, which is what a mechanic can do.  Can I identify bits and pieces of my car?  Sure.  Do I know how to fix them?  Hah!  Not a chance.  Same with programming.  Knowing you're looking at code doesn't mean you're a programmer.  Following a tutorial also doesn't make you one.  It means you followed a tutorial.  There is a minimum level of skill required to actually be one.  How you learn it is immaterial, but you **have** to have that level of skill to participate meaningfully.

Comment: Fun fact: Jeff Atwood posted a definition in his [last blog post](https://blog.codinghorror.com/what-does-stack-overflow-want-to-be-when-it-grows-up/): `Q&A for professional and enthusiast programmers. By that we mean: People who either already have a job as a programmer, or could potentially be hired as a programmer today if they wanted to be.`  Personally, I think that's more strict that we need to be, but it clearly shows that there is a minimum barrier to entry that's far higher than, "I want to be a programmer".

Comment: @fbueckert two things. One: your response to my response is trash. It was pretty clear I was talking about how little the average person knows and that I was not arguing that reading code makes you a enthusiast. Two: You should have lead with that. Atwood hasn't touched SO in a professional capacity since 2012, but I guess his opinion still matters. gg

Comment: @WelcomeOverflow I think I started a new account because the first one become so overthrown with downvotes and from then on I was more careful about how to post questions and what types of questions that I would add. But anyway. I experienced what I experienced. My last question got a downvote and I dont see why its necessary to downvote just because someone doesnt "get" something straight away. Apparently people here think that you should at least get what they think you should get, whatever that is and if there is a minimum knowledge required to post here, then say it or write about it.

Comment: @exceed Because downvotes are a judgement of the post's quality.  We're trying to build a repository of knowledge.  That means we have specific standards that *must* be met.  You can't build a house that will stand for decades if you just let anybody pour the concrete, frame the walls, and figure it's, "good enough".  That attitude leads to a broken house in just a few years, which is why we are so exacting.  We want to do it *right*, not just, "good enough".

Comment: @exceed `I dont see why its necessary to downvote just because someone doesnt "get" something straight away.` You have no idea why someone votes up or down unless they tell you (which is frowned upon).  Nor is a DV a referendum on you nor your value as a human.  All it means is that *this question does not show any research effort, is unclear or not useful*.  To be clear, the ***question*** is not useful, not you.  If you are getting lots of them, consider the possibly that a number of people over a period of time think that a number of your posts are unclear, not useful or not well researched

Comment: @WelcomeOverflow If thats the case then I have misunderstood the downvotes and its certainly good to know that not everyone thinks im a complete idiot as I do try my best to do research before question although in programming I realize that im not that bright, but i do try to learn more and more.

Comment: @exceed and here you just summarized the issue with how Stack is being seen: you as a new user equal a downvote to 'the community thinks I'm dumb'. Nowonder you think we are rude and unwelcoming. But (bear with me) what if you are wrong, and that is **not** what the community thinks, or expr sales with their vote?

Comment: @Patrice I guess maybe the word "downvote" has a negative mental effect. If there was a word that was clear that it meant that the voting was based on how usefull the question was for the site, then I certainly wouldnt think much of it in the first place. Some places has "recommend" or similar, maybe if you use something like "Interesting" or something less negative it would be better. "Downvote" just hits you in the stomach. Thats just my opinion though.

Comment: @Patrice From my point of view it still is difficult for new people to be here if you change the downvote word, so that was just an example. People here seem to have way to high expectations of the knowledge you have, so if you ask a question that is hard for you but easy for other people they just want to close the question, sometimes without even telling you. I get that you want a DB with only interesting and usefull questions, but I dont think you can have it both ways without making people feeling unwelcome.

Answer (score 111):

I do think we need to manage expectations.

We are, at the core, a site where we use the basics of the English language to communicate solutions to programming problems. Anybody who can do that should be welcomed, because that is the nice thing to do.

I do believe that the "enthusiast" part is due to the fact that nobody really cares if someone here gets money for applying the solution. We don't care what a persons day job is (or gender, skin color, income, shoe size or any other variable that's not useful to the above goal of solving programming problems).

It appears to me that people understand the "enthusiast" part to mean everybody should feel welcome here. Whether they can use the English language to communicate programming problems or not.

And quite frankly, I don't want to welcome anybody who is not able to do so. If someone cannot even use the browsers free, inbuilt spellchecker or cannot ask a coherent question or does not answer but instead tells their life story... great. But why here? They can go start a blog and write whatever they want. I will not stop them. But this site was not built for that and I wonder why I should be welcoming anybody not caring for the rules.

It's like a bar. They *should* be welcoming to any customer. But if a drunk stumbles in and pukes on the floor, nobody would expect the staff to be "welcoming".

When I joined, I read the rules. The tour. I tried to get it right. I made a few minor mistakes. I looked at how others behaved and corrected those mistakes. That is how you integrate with a community.

I'm not sure why those things aren't taught any more.

I do teach my apprentices how to move in professional communities. That this *isn't* Facebook. That this *isn't* the place to talk smack or be rude to people, *especially* not if you are the one who needs help. That you need to present your case the best case possible, do your own homework before you ask for help.

So yes, we need to manage expectations. But new developers don't magically appear (although I'm sure SE would love that). Somebody teaches them. So we need to make sure that whoever teaches programming, also teaches how to move around and behave yourself in professional communities like ours.

If you are lucky, you have a responsible friend, who will keep you from stumbling into that bar totally drunk. We need to *be* that friend. We need to show people how to behave *before* they puke on the floor.

So every time we see someone in the office call SO "unfriendly" we should call them out and offer to show them how to work it out. Every time we have an intern or apprentice, we should teach them how to find help here, instead of just rolling our eyes saying "oh come on just google it". Every time a friend asks for programming help, we should take them by the hand and teach them how to use SO instead of just sending them a link over IM.

The world is not only bits and bytes. I agree we should be welcoming, but not *here*. If it's on here, it's too late. Here, the puke is on the floor, we need a cleanup crew, not a responsible friend.

We need to be better at helping *before* people get downvoted here. In meatspace. Where it counts.

Comment: Would it be safe to surmise your last point as, "By the time they get downvoted here, it's too late." ?

Comment: Basically, yes. Their expectation is set and we cannot cater to it *and* keep this site's quality. There is no welcoming way to say "you failed". We need to go out and make sure they don't fail in the first place.

Comment: @nvoigt fully agree with you... that's where our philosophy of "it's against the post, not the poster" is hurting us, I feel. The veterans here are detached from their posts and they know what it means. The newbies **cannot** have such a detachment at first (and saying "they should"... well doesn't change squat).

Comment: @Patrice Indeed, I think this is something to learn too, because it's **not obvious** or intuitive. After all, the account (aka the person) is docked points and maybe loses privileges when we downvote a post. So saying "it's only the post" is simply not true. People don't understand that because it's so obviously wrong, it *always* affects the account. It takes a reasonable self-confidence (boosted by enough internet points to spare) to say "oh a downvote, I don't care that my account lost points, I will take that as a signal to improve".

Comment: @nvoigt Most people who are upset about downvotes aren't upset about the points.  Most of them are brand new accounts that aren't even losing any points when they're downvoted (because they have none to lose), and because they aren't here to get points, they're here to get an answer to their question.  They're upset because someone telling them that their question is problematic isn't (in their mind) helping them get an answer.  They're not used to having an expectation of a high quality question and people telling them when their question isn't good enough.  Most places don't do that.

Comment: @Servy I don't disagree. I'm just saying they are not open to the "it's about the post, not the poster" argument, because it does not resonate with their reality. If one has only one question, the account *is* the post.

Comment: "I'm not sure why those things aren't taught any more." I think you're going to need to explain this a little more. Was there actually a time when professors gave more instructions than "if you have any problems coding you can ask on StackExchange" or are you talking about something else? (No really, this is essentially what I was told in my one class, with no further instructions, leaving me with the temptation to ask coding questions on the cooking site.)

Comment: @Laurel Well, maybe I'm old, but when I was a kid, a teacher would drag us to the local library and *show us* how the indexing system worked. How to find books. How to read and cross reference books. To keep to the rules because if silence is demanded and you get loud you will be escorted out. To me it seems students today did not get taught how the internet works. They were supposed to figure it out on their own. And we see the results here. Some make it, some don't. But "some make it, some don't" is not how you teach people. That's a horrible guideline.

Comment: @nvoigt Yeah I was taught about how to use the library and also basic computer things like very basic search skills and the fact that you should never ever give out any personal information online. I was also taught how to do basic debugging in programming classes. But none of this explicitly covered etiquette for asking questions online.

Comment: The puking barfly analogy is spot-on.  It seems to me that SO corporate has confused "welcoming everybody" with "welcoming everybody's content" which is exactly what SO was *not* supposed to be.  We judge content, not people, but the corollary is that people who only produce crap content are *not* welcome here.

Comment: @Laurel If you ever see that professor again, please punch them in the face. When they ask you why, tell them to post the question on Stack Exchange.

Comment: Great answer, nvoigt!

Comment: Just a side note on "But new developers don't magically appear (although I'm sure SE would love that). Somebody teaches them." My interest in programming just magically appeared because I wanted to learn it myself. I just googled stuff. I had no mentors or anything. So while that might apply for many, some of us are just random people looking for knowledge on our own.

Answer (score 41):

I completely agree with the premise of the question, but after a myriad of Q&A following the blog post and the be (even) nice(r) initiative, my current understanding is:

1. 99%ish of people using SO just read answers that are useful for them and love the site. They have no idea about the flame-anti-SO war going on (basically a few bloggers who do not like the site). They do not care, and shouldn't - they are the masses this site aims to serve (this is my opinion).
2. Of those who bother to actually participate actively by asking, 99.99999%ish are first timers or almost that, without the very important understanding that **writing a question is an important job that comes with big responsibility, with often more work needed to be done on creating the question than answering it**. I think this is the typical feeling more **experienced users** have about questions and their askers
3. The most important part - after reading some SO history as well, **I am no longer sure SE management agrees with SO veterans** on point 2. I may be wrong, but at least that is the feeling I get from all these posts. Even if this is not true, I think in any case many experienced users **feel** this may be the case, and as someone mentioned, there is no arguing with generalized, non-backed-up claims like that.

Thinking about a solution to  your specific question, I wonder if a new user coming to ask a question and sees:

> Welcome to SO. Questions here are expected to be very high quality and within parameters listed in the help section. This often entails much more work than new users expect. Questions must be researched thoroughly, carefully worded, and clear. If you have the slightest doubt your question is of this quality, reconsider your post until you are better prepared.

would feel welcome? Even if not, and we do manage to stop a lot of the low quality questions, should we care? Users and management may differ on the answer. There is also the issue of people with good questions - are we sure enough of these do not get frightened by such a message? I am for it, but it will require some beta-testing in my opinion.

**Addendum**

As some of the experienced people mention in the comments, another realization of many is that

4. Those 99.999%ish new users will ignore all text thrown at them.

Perhaps there is no hope, without drastic measures.

Comment: If people do get frightened by the amount of effort they have to put in to contribute to the site...I'm not seeing a downside.  Stack Overflow has volumes more questions and traffic than most every other site out there.  Slowing that down isn't the worst thing in the world.

Comment: @Makoto could not agree more. I wish I *felt* SE agreed.

Comment: Honestly, I truly don't believe that these messages to new beginners will help whatsoever and let me explain why. SO's ethos was about collating quality content and having it one place but for those new users that is *not* what SO is about. For them, SO is about getting their problem solved (which incidentally is a purpose but not *the* purpose). So when their low quality / broad / opinionated question gets closed, down-voted and they directed the [tour] or the [ask] guide, they get the false impression and take it personally that the site isn't working as intended due a group of toxic users.

Comment: @Script47 I have seen the argument before and can even relate. I do think though that most of what we do is "unwelcoming" (in this same down-vote feels nasty sense) **after** the question is asked. If you explicitly say they may not be ready (good enough...) to ask before, I wonder if it can stem the tide. Consider even a 10% reduction in terrible questions - that reads to me like a giant amount of questions, and perhaps it will spread the news more quickly that you need to be "an elitist", to quote some bloggers, to post here.

Comment: If providing an error log, explaining your question coherently and including relevant code for *free* help is too much to ask, then that in itself speaks volumes about the people asking the questions.

Comment: @Script47 I have enough faith in humanity that at least a few of those you describe will pause on such a message, and reconsider. You could of course, make it harsher. Not sure if SE would want this at all though, so the discussion may be moot.

Comment: For sure, SE does nothing to prepare new users to use the site.  Help and How to ask dont mention the most common cause for DVs.  So shame on SE.  Double shame that someone had to develop a site (IDownVoatedBecau.se) with does a much better job of things.  **However**, the vast majority of new users dont read anything anyway (no Informed badge) so there are faults across the spectrum

Comment: Pushing information into their faces! no blinky light, only a short, concise, polite, yet harsh message. I do not think this was really attempted before.

Comment: "They" (the Diamondbacks at SE) claim to not want to inhibit access by imposing requirements.  But then, you cant be surprised when strangers come in and take a dump on the floor. You also cant be surprised when other users are irritated at the smell and general decay.  Seems that allowing new users access for the first 3 questions or maybe just 3 DVs (net) then you have to read an Improved How to Ask would be a decent middle ground.  More users might understand about editing posts, voting and so forth.

Comment: @Disaffected1070452 That may be I good idea. My suggested inhibitor is "softer" in the sense it does not actually prevent asking, just throws a warning - managing expectations.

Comment: @kabanus That's what the question/answer ban does; gives the user a warning that their content has not been received well, and that they're in danger of being banned.  Wanna know how many actually take that to heart?  The answer is unfortunately few.  We don't hear about it until they hit the ban, and then it's the fault of the system for preventing them from stinking up the place more.

Comment: They already ignore those.  There are reminders that pop up to vote and/or accept an answer even one that says "_____ need votes too" if you upvote many many more As than Qs or vice versa.

Comment: @fbueckert every one here is such a pessimist. I guess it comes with old SO age. I hope it is just a feeling and not the truth, since many users seems to be saying the same thing - there is no hope (save perhaps, drastic measures like preventing questions until a certain rep etc.)

Comment: @Disaffected1070452 I gather then the general consensus is not one with a positive outlook on the future of SO, following all the comments above.

Comment: I would rather gargle with broken glass than answer another question on SO.

Comment: @Disaffected1070452 If it makes you feel better, you cracked me up hard.

Comment: You almost got there, but it is also important to note that the people that actually care about quality on SO make up 0.000000000000000000000000001% of the userbase, so Stack Exchange does not value them or their opinions very highly.

Comment: @kabanus Pessimist, or realist?

Comment: @TinyGiant I did not want to state it explicitly. Seems bad putting it in writing (though if you read some of the comments, seems this is the gist of everyone's feelings today on meta). I asked a question about this, and Tim even answered a pretty good answer, but I really think this is going to end up costing money (in the sense that the site will break after enough years of this trend).

Comment: @kabanus I think they recognize this and that is why they aren't touching the core Q&A product and are directing all of their resources towards building these side-projects. They know that the core product is going down hill fast and the only way to keep making money is to build these side projects. Hell in a few years we probably won't have public Q&A at all anymore, it will just be teams paying for hosting. So much less overhead when you don't have to support the public or moderate anything.

Comment: @fbueckert both I guess?

Comment: @TinyGiant so at least one day we can say we are part of the only few who cared (going to extinction).

Comment: Part of it. a big part, seems to fall to the generation coming of age.  When you get awards and trophies just for showing up, it can come as a surprise to them that in many cases you may have to spend some effort just in order not to fail.  So, they post a no effort, no research "I just want a code that..." type post and it gets DVed and closed.  They think that SO is cruel and mean.  The real moral to the story is with no effort, you will fall on the wrong side of the bell curve. Dont even try to explain that SO is here to help everyone not just them. "But I need help!"

Comment: @disa You say the help center doesn't cover the downvote reasons? But it does! Just that it's worded as "You should do X." instead of "If you are downvoted, you should do X".

Comment: You're unsure about SE management agreeing with SO veterans? Allow me to put that doubt to rest. SE management doesn't agree with SO vets. I was contacted by management and given a bit of help by them. The person I talked to made it very clear that "convincing them[SO veterans] that the site[ SO ] is for everyone is hard sometimes". Now you can be sure about the divide between SE management and SO vets who hate beginners.

Comment: @Steve You seem to be taking things personally. The vets want the site to remain what it always was - the #1 go to resource for most of the programming world. To make that happen asking a question must entail a level of expertise that is high - I meant what I said, asking is harder than answering. Try to remember those vets you are malign against are the ones answering nearly everything, and are the reason people even bother asking here.

Comment: @Steve Also, to be clear, management likely has to thank these people for every dollar they make. I started contributing barely two years ago, but the vets here built this giant trove of knowledge. I really cannot justify anyone speaking of them in anyway but a thankful manner.

Comment: @kabanus except that they also make it damn near impossible for beginners to do anything here. Keep in mind that I was just talking about SE management's view of who SO is for and how that aligns with the SO veterans view of who SO is for. Raising the barrier for entry is not going to change SO. As it stands now all of the highest voted questions on SO are low quality barely within the rules questions that were asked at least 5 years ago.

Comment: @kabanus I can. They're gate keeping too harshly. That's not okay.

Comment: @Steve Simple questions are not low quality the first time they are asked. The problem is they have since been asked a lot more - that is what people treat as low quality.

Comment: @Steve You miss the point - they are building a knowledgebase. You are coming here expecting tutoring. They built the site years before you came - why should they change for you?

Comment: @kabanus and would you say that the people treating these questions as low quality are mostly new comers or veterans?

Comment: @kabanus I'm not expecting tutoring. I'm expecting to participate in building a wealth of knowledge curated with the goal of helping as many people improve/get past bugs as possible.

Comment: @kabanus Just disengage.  There's no winning here.  There's no way to convince them of our purpose.  [We've been here long before](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/375766/1197934)

Comment: @Steve If you truly want to contribute, then I think if you stick around you will see the value in these strict, no fun, zealously kept regulations. This is not vanity, but it does take a steep learning curve to see.

Comment: @fbueckert I think Steve sounds much more moderate than some contributors antagonized by the site.

Comment: @kabanus They do, at first.  It's the obstinate refusal to acknowledge anything that doesn't fit their expectations that makes it worthless to argue with them.  Feel free to continue, but it's just going to be frustrating.

Comment: @kabanus I'm not saying there's no value in it. I'm just saying that it's strict to the point of preventing people from using SO, correctly or otherwise. The rules are getting in the way more than they're helping at this point, as proven by the large amount of rule breaking content that is rewarded, low quality content that either slips under the radar or gets uploaded to the site, and the negative impact this unwelcoming behavior has had on the Stack Exchange networks reputation. I've had coworkers flatly refuse to use this sight because "the people there are assholes". The problem is real.

Comment: @Steve I will finish by this - I do not think the sites reputations has been damaged at all. Those same coworkers will not contribute, but they will definitely find (and use) answers from SO. This is how it should be for most programmers. With regards to the low quality, well, that is a concern of everyone, but the general consensus (and I do think management will agree here) that stuff slips "under the radar" is due to the obscene amount of low effort questions - askers multiply much faster than answerers. Anyway, try to stick around, maybe you will get used to it.

Comment: @kabanus yeah a certain someone and I have gone at it on this subject too many times before. There's really no compromise people who think SO is functioning perfectly. We can't even agree on what SO is for. It's remarkable honestly. My exchanging words with them is a waste of time. Their mind is already made.

Answer (score 40):

This sounds good.

So...time to ask the $1,000,000 question.

## What are we really expecting?

---

The problem that I see is that what we think is "acceptable" on the site stems from the base principles:

- Your question must be clearly worded
- Your question must be related to programming, or tools used by programmers such as IDEs
- *If* your question is about an error, it should include the code used to generate that error
- If you're asking about a design pattern or algorithm, you should be as descriptive as possible and code is not necessarily required

...but then you see [questions which appear to be entirely too broad](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/353940/1079354) treated as the norm.

Don't get me started on duplicates and poor questions.  The expectation for a question which is a dupe is for it to remain as a dupe.  We can be expected to delete questions which aren't serving as "good signposts", although that too is subjective and depends on which reviewer you get that day.

Before we can do anything about setting expectations for others, we have to set the expectations for ourselves *here*.  There's way too much in the way of hidden rules and tribal knowledge that we simply learn and divine through many, many hours on Meta that can't readily be translated for anyone else.

Comment: Which "we" are you specifically talking about? ["We, the (moderately or otherwise) concerned users](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/373158)? "We, the Stack Overflow investors"? "[We who just want ur valuable halp - URGENT)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/367092/2564301)"?

Comment: @usr2564301: If you can read this message, it is *safe* to assume the first.

Comment: "Tribal knowledge", I like that. Word around the campfire is that it is also very hard to manage expectations for people who are rushing towards clicking that "ask question" button :) You can't show the way to those who's feet are like the wind  and eyes are like the hawk.

Comment: Suppose I am a beginner, and non-professional programmer. I use JavaScript (consider this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75643430/chart-js-how-can-%c4%b1-remove-ticks-duplicate-data/75654142?noredirect=1#comment137397979_75654142 ) and Python only to draw graphs for my scientific work, without even scratching the surface of programming. So, are my questions for this site (first question)? And, second, If they are, and If I am not allowed to post them, because I had previously was stupid enough to ask a more stupid question, were am I supposed to ask?

Comment: So, is the saying: "There isn't stupid question" not applicable here? I'm not talking about the clear offenders and trolls. However, when my question, as a beginner is not so "on the point", because of a basic misunderstanding, I think the best way to help this person is to understand his question, and direct him to a place, were he is more likely to be answered, instead of blocking him and decreasing his reputation. Even without Stackoverflow, I still can feel the programming community is too unwelcoming for amateurs. And this was supposed to be one of the best such Q&A site.

Comment: @MarkoKolaksazov In a setting where you have a person who is willing to educate and instruct people with personalized guidance will tend to agree that "there are no stupid questions". The reality for this site, however, is that low quality questions waste the time of potential answerers and visitors, which negatively affects the experience for most people involved. I'm afraid that you should not expect that kind of personalized guidance here, because it does not scale to the number of incoming questions, and hampers the utility of the site for other users.

Comment: @MarkoKolaksazov As per you being question banned, the mechanism is automatic and it depends mostly on you improving the existing questions. Read [this FAQ](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255583/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th) carefully, and if you wish, you may ask for help on how to improve certain questions here on Meta Stack Overflow.

Comment: I agree with your first comment. Moreover, many questions that arise don't view new topics, but they tend to be duplicates of previously asked questions. This happened to me more than once and is very often amongst beginners. What is important, is that nobody wants to ask repeating questions, if they could be answered after searching in the previous questions. However most beginners, including myself are often not sure about the nature of the question itself in the first place, and exactly that's why they ask duplicating and off-topic question: because they simply can't understand the basis!

Comment: Btw, I just asked ChatGPT about the topic in my first comment, and I received immediate, complete and working answer! So I guess this site will soon be replaced, at least for the complete beginners, and it may serve only amongst the very specialized and advanced professionals in the field of programming!

Comment: @MarkoKolaksazov One would counter-argue that 1) knowing how to search the web is a critical skill which anyone should have and does not depend on how new you are to a particular subject; and 2) some duplicates could still be useful if they serve as a good signpost to the answer, when search engines fail. The excuse for blatantly off-topic questions is much weaker though, because that suggests people weren't paying attention when taking the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and reading the ([help pages](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) on the subject.

Comment: @MarkoKolaksazov Reliance on any LLM for programming has been talked about over and over again. Good that it worked for you in that case, and we are not telling you not to use it. But one must understand that it won't work every time and may subtly mislead you with grave consequences. It does _not_ replace Stack Overflow.

Comment: 1) It depends, even only because if you are very new to a subject you may not even search for the right thing (or recognize the issue); 2) Yes, this is very true (especially in some of my cases), however, I still acknowledge, that given more knowledge about the subjects (e.g. data types in Python is a great example), much more of these duplicates could be reduced or avoided!

Comment: A very fresh example is my question (the last I was allowed to post): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77898679/matplotlib-valueerror-trying-to-find-out-indices-of-the-combinations-that-have When I certainly know, that I have different data types, I can search and easily find how to convert them (And I won't post anything stupid here). However, if I don't know that for arrays I should use ```numpy.logical_and()```, instead of ```&```, how can I know, that for these different data types there is a different way to work with them. (remember that sometimes the operations are very similar)

Comment: @MarkoKolaksazov 1) that would be fine, because asking a single duplicate question does not lead to a question ban. That requires a pattern of asking several poorly received questions. 2) For what it's worth, a Duck Duck Go search with the query `numpy operations and` gave me the API reference the that same function as the first result. So it could come down again to a matter of knowing how to search, and the site has intentionally optimized the experience for those who search. Alas, the site itself was not designed to fill in the knowledge gap on how to search the web.

Comment: I am on a different opinion here, because these repeating questions are so annoying even to me as an amateur!! And none of them on my topic!! Speaking of searching the numpy operators, how should I know, that there are different numpy operators in the first place, and why after searching the ```ValueError``` I did not receive immediately the answer, but only very similar (even the same duplicate answers), which are irrevelant and did not help me at all!!

Comment: Not to mention the error itself suggested me two very different (both unhelpfull) functions a.all() and a.any()!

Comment: @MarkoKolaksazov Whether the question is suitable has **absolutely nothing to do with** how easy it is to answer. It has everything to do with *meeting the site's quality standards for how the question is asked*. The golden rule is: imagine that someone else had already posted your question, exactly as you are writing it, and someone else answered it. Now imagine that you have the **same underlying problem, but with completely different code**. Would you be *able to find* your question? Would you be *happy* to see the question as written? Could the *answers be helpful* to the new you?

Comment: In your case, the question is a **clear** duplicate. You asked: "What is the meaning of this message, and why am I receiving it in the first place?" The linked duplicate has many answers explaining exactly that. The reason why the error message suggests those two different options is **exactly the same reason why** there is an error message: because your code **could mean** either of those things (or several other possibilities), and Numpy refuses to guess which one you mean. But most likely, what you really meant was to use `&` instead of `and`. Fortunately, **the duplicate explains this**.

Comment: In fact, the example used in the duplicate matches your use case (even though there are **many** other possible use cases that would give the same error), and the top answer shows the correct solution for you as the first line of code. So I really don't understand the objection. "Speaking of searching the numpy operators, how should I know, that there are different numpy operators in the first place" - **there aren't**; `&` is a perfectly ordinary Python operator which Numpy has overloaded.

Comment: "if I don't know that for arrays I should use numpy.logical_and(), instead of &" - no, you have missed the point completely. `numpy.logical_and` is **just** a function that applies the `&` operator, offering a few more options and also allowing you to use it as a higher-order function. The **actual** problem is that `&` and `and` are different in Python (which is true whether or not you use Numpy).

Comment: In short: despite the fact that a couple other people liked it, the answer you got directly is low quality. The problem is an extremely common duplicate and we have much better information for it elsewhere. (I can guarantee you that the code mozway offered you in the comments does, in fact, work. If you found an issue with it, you would need to debug it properly, and possibly ask a new question with a proper MRE around that code.)

Comment: (finally: for future questions, please use a title and tags that describe **what you are asking about, not** the underlying problem you are trying to solve or task you are trying to complete by getting an answer.)

Comment: Thank you very much! What I understand now confirms my experience with Python with its strictness with the data types. You are completely right that my question is one of the too many duplicates and doesn't add something new. And, I start to wonder if something couldn't be done to reduce these questions, e.g: in this case only one posted question is necessary, but this question must be visible well enough from everyone with little knowledge on the topic.

Comment: In that case, even better would be for anyone who starts learning Python to have in mind this dependency of the language on the data types, and to be very well aware of this before doing anything with the language.

Comment: Thus, you can post all the questions that somehow have the same underlying problem, and there can still be added one more. However, this can include thousands of posts, but completely useless to people with low education on the language. This leads to 2 things: 1) discouragement of beginners, and if you overcome the 1st somehow, 2) lower standards, which will encourage the superficial understanding of the language.

Answer (score 15):

I posted this on meta 4 years ago:

[The Good, The Bad & The Ugly](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266361/the-good-the-bad-the-ugly)

> **TLDR**
>
> Give new users and persistent offenders (who write poorly received posts) a tutorial they must complete before they can post, which highlights good and bad posts, along with reasoning as to why they are judged as they are.
>
> The idea behind it is to educate these users about what the community expects to a degree when it comes to posting. The knock on effect is to hopefully reduce the number of bad posts as well as reduce the amount of time experienced user spend explaining the same things over and over again in comments and via voting.

I truly believe something like this would set expectations to a certain degree by informing users what the community expects when it comes to posting.

I'm fully aware it won't stop the tide of poorly written posts, but it might inform a small portion of the users of our expectations.

Comment: That proposal would help. But I am suggesting changing expectations of potential users before they have even started posting their first question.

Comment: @Raedwald that's what my post suggests, it is designed so that all new users would have to go through the process before they can post as well as persistent offenders.

Comment: No, I mean even before they clock on "Ask A Question" and (perhaps) get transported to your tutorial. I mean perhaps even before they have first *visited* the site.

Comment: @Raedwald, before they even get to visit (and find the answer to their question)? That would kill this site like lightning.

Comment: @outflak No, it would not. Managing expectations of *posters* would not inhibit finding an answer to a question. Many read Wikipedia; far fewer edit it.

Comment: Again, software is a factor. ;-)

Comment: @Raedwald How does SE change expectations of people "before they have first *visited* the site"? I'm honestly listening, but it does seem like a tall order. How would you achieve that?

Comment: That reminds me of my tutorial proposal from 2009: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/521/6309

Answer (score 2):

I agree entirely that expectation-management is important.  And with the rise of algorithmic evolution for picking solutions to problems, I proposed users have to tick "Pre-Flight" checkboxes:

[Pre-flight screening checklist for first/early posts--adaptively pick three items, tune with metrics](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265671/pre-flight-screening-checklist-for-first-early-posts-adaptively-pick-three-item)

This list could adapt based on the tag, and see what effects it was happening on the average new user's question.

I'm still a broken record wanting to see this idea implemented.  If SO won't try it as a feature itself, maybe it could be done as one of the new "research" projects--perhaps someone wanting to do a machine-learning thing.

Answer (score -1):

I would like to once again like to draw attention to this feature request: [Make “What's on topic of this site?” visible](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/301363/make-whats-on-topic-of-this-site-visible)

Things like "Tour", "FAQ", and "How to Ask" all sound super *optional* and *passive*, so I think new users can hardly be blamed for skipping over these. When they get to the "Ask Question" page, all they get is this super unhelpful set of instructions:

[image: The current How to Ask side box text with its very unhelpful text. I mean really, even r/WritingPrompts has a more informative sidebar text...]

This box is pretty much the only thing that new question askers are guaranteed to see, so why aren't we cramming more salient information into this text box? Things like what's allowed on this site and what's not, what will get your question closed/deleted, the guideline that you're supposed check that your question hasn't already been asked before, etc. A new user can get to this point and have absolutely *no idea* that all these policies and rules exist. There needs to be something that alerts them in a *more prominent way* that these things exist.

No, "visit the help center" and "asking help" doesn't count. Links with those names are practically invisible. There needs to be a clear direct call-to-action "Read These Guidelines First or Else We Are Not Responsible for What Happens to You" in this box. You know, typical [JIT stuff](https://blog.codinghorror.com/the-just-in-time-theory/).

"Users are lazy and they won't read the text anyway." Well, they sure as heck aren't going to read something that they don't even know exists. But if it's right in their face as they're writing their question, and it tells them that they're *supposed* to read it, then I think they'd be more likely to read it. (Now obviously, I don't think changing this will solve all the problems, but I think it could help at least a little.)

I'd rather this site be preventive, not reactive.

Comment: A [question asking wizard](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/369682/ask-a-question-wizard-prototype) is being worked on that should give more guidance.

Comment: "There needs to be a clear direct call-to-action "Read These Guidelines First or Else We Are Not Responsible for What Happens to You" in this box." There is.  Before anyone is allowed to ask their first question they're shown a page that tells them that this site is different, and tells them that they need to read the page on how to ask before continuing, and doesn't let them ask their question until they acknowledge that they've read the page. Every single person that *ever* asks a question either has read the how to ask page, or lied and claimed that they did. So [meta-tag:status-completed].

Comment: @Servy Oh, it's been a long since I first asked a question here, so I was unaware of that. But I think it would still be helpful to display a link to these guidelines more prominently in the sidebar, so that for a new user's 2nd or 3rd question, it's still there as a reminder. You know, reinforcement learning and whatnot.

Comment: Agree this big yellow box is basically wasted.  Don't comprehend the downvotes, [nor to my suggestion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/377235/211160).  The site seems to want to stay frozen mostly in time, with an eternity of off-topic questions culled by an increasingly irate volunteer army.  :-/

Comment: Additionally, if you make the window narrow enough, the adaptive layout puts the yellow box *below* pretty much everything on the ask question page. I think it would be better if the yellow box appeared at the top of the page, because then users would get a chance to read it *before* they start writing their question.

Answer (score -12):

## Software *is* a factor, among all else

*Entrepreneur, Linux amateur, and PM in training here... I represent the annoying guy. ;-)*

1. A change in awareness of "expectations" does require some changes to the SE website software, sooner or later.
2. Software changes to the website require coding time from the workforce. *...As in, it will go to the SE PM's desk, he'll inquire about the budget with accounting, then ask if it fits with the workload of the programmers at his Monday afternoon meeting.*
3. SE is all employee-written; they don't take public contributions for the code on SourceForge or GitHub or the like; it's private GitHub-ish. So, they are limited on their software writing workforce. *([Will Stack Overflow's engine be open sourced?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35/will-stack-overflows-engine-be-open-sourced))*

As for whether your post is a good idea or not, I'm too new to know, but looks like the experts agree with you. I'm learning from y'all. But, just sayin'...

It could be that, behind wonderful ideas—whatever they are—*not* being implemented could be a logistics-budgeting decision. In addition to all the upvoted answers on this, ***I think UX software of SE and the workforce to write it wouldn't be entirely off topic.***

Comment: Hey there. It's unclear why the link was duplicated, and also what exactly you want to cite from there. There are 10 answers, that vary wildly in scope and topic, and it's really not obvious what you want a reader to understand from it.

Comment: Thanks, I might have gotten the same link twice, I wanted two. But, you're also right about it being confusing. Is brevity better?

Comment: Not sure to which extent I agree with your points, but I like this better, yes.

Comment: Well, this is a meta friend! Please dissent and tell me why I'm all wrong and all wet! :-)

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314287/come-take-a-look-at-our-new-contributor-indicator/314304#314304

Comment: Yep, thanks! So many of these ideas have already been discussed on some level. That's kinda' the point of SE, that we all ask similar questions. I see. I agree. I'm doing my best where I have the power to. Keep it comin'! :-)

Comment: Why do you think the software needs to change dramatically beyond "here is a field to ask your question" and "here is a place to see others' questions and answers"?

Comment: @Makoto I never said "dramatically". And, I'm not advocating that the software change. I'm only stating that, knowing how business works, there is probably some bean-counting going on that stifles good ideas—yours or mine—from being implemented.

Answer (score -23):

> "If 90% of them take it in their stride and improve.."

People tend to adopt/change behavior only after several failed attempts and then continue testing rule limits time to time.  So the problem is not with expectations. You can't distinct those situations externally.

Also definition of failed expectations should be extended to cover situation "good question - zero response" (I mean not only closed question). What can be done with this? Nothing.

Based on my observations new authors become rude and start talking about "toxic SO community" not because of just "failed expectations" reason but because of feeling (if you want "false feeling") of injustice and unrespect in more complex social interactions than closed "help me with my homework" question but e.g. in situation "I spend a lot of time to prepare nice question, my post get a lot of upvotes first day, but next day it was found by reviewers and..." Other type of complex interactions with site that lead to "feeling of injustice" was described by [George M](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/377101/be-more-welcoming-by-managing-expectations/377123#377123), it includes discussing duplicates on Meta.

Comment: '*People tend to adopt/change behavior only after several failed attempts and then continue testing rule limits. So the problem is not with expectations.*' - The blunt truth is that most people just want their answer, period. They don't care about their failed attempts or the issues with their question or the [tour] or any other advice that isn't directly related to them solving their problem.

Comment: That seems like a _false expectation_ that we would wish to suppress. Just because one question was not closed doesn't mean that future questions of similar quality or off-topicness won't.

Comment: As a side note, please focus your edits on substantial improvements, and avoid making too many of those. An excessive streak of edits will continuously bump the question up for little reason, and is kind of annoying.

Comment: I was not informed about it, so thank you for information. But I have no motivation so can't promise anything.

Comment: A nice question and a good question can be two very different things.  I often see people defending their questions as, "legitimate questions".  Yeah, they're having the problem.  We don't dispute that.  But at the same time, we have quality standards.  How, "legit" their problem is doesn't really matter.  All that does is question quality and topicality.

Comment: I do not want to discuss "have new authors right to feel something?". This is just my observations. Take them, compare with yours.

Comment: Then you're answering the wrong question, which is explicitly tagged discussion.

Comment: This question can be answered different ways. But for me this aspect "have new authors right to feel unwelcoming?" is less important. For me was important to explain "why they feel unwelcoming" as I see it.

Comment: I can't discuss seriously "rights to feel". I can discuss "Should I ignore your feelings". But this is second, after "investigating why you feel smth". IMHO.

Comment: I find most new users have unreasonable expectations, and respond with hostility when those expectations are not met.  Especially when those unmet expectations occur with enforcement of quality standards.  We're not discussing their right to feel unwelcoming, nor whether we should ignore them.  We're discussing if we can alleviate that feeling entirely by properly managing those expectations.  This entire movement is predicated on the fact that SO, and SE in general, has failed in doing so.

Comment: @fbueckert  I can't agree with this: "most new users... respond with hostility when those expectations are not met" in word "most" and in pretend to know theirs "expectations". "unwelcome SO myth" is result of conflicts in small number of cases, and in more complex social iteractions.  And I think that it is still a valid answer on the question.

Comment: SO specifically prevents you from participating after a certain number of failures. People generally can't try try again here.

Comment: @Steve Prevents who? New auhtors? Can't find anything about it. I event can't imagine how this could be organized.

Comment: @RomanPokrovskij Look up question and answer bans on SO

Comment: Ok. You mean temporal bans. This do not "prevent new authors from participating" and do not try to change manhood nature: "try it again, try several times, try several different ways". This how intellect works.

Answer (score -33):

I don't feel welcome in places that do not want me, so I don't think that managing expectations would help.

For example, let's assume, for the sake of argument, that  Server Fault is still a place for [system administrators in a professional capacity](https://meta.serverfault.com/questions/1760/server-fault-is-for-system-administrators-in-a-professional-capacity?rq=1). I know that I am not welcome here because of this description.

You say that Breitbart hasn't made you feel unwelcome? Okay. I say that Server Fault *has* made me feel unwelcome, by putting up a big sign that says **"You aren't welcome here"**.

> but isn't the case of you feeling unwelcomed on you?

Yes, yes it is. But I still feel unwelcomed.

> let's say I'm having a party and I've invited a bunch of friends and you (a complete stranger) happen to walk past and want to join in, if I say 'Sorry, only people who are invited or at the very least know me are invited.' am I now in danger of being unwelcoming?

Whether or not you're "being" unwelcoming is beside the point. The point is that I "feel" unwelcomed.

To quote the infamous blog post: "When someone tells you how they feel,  you can pack up your magnifying glass and clue kit, cuz that’s the answer. You’re done."

If this is the logic that SO is using, then this is an unwinnable battle. There will always be people that "feel unwelcome", despite everything.

Comment: *@Houseman but isn't the case of you feeling unwelcomed on you? Meaning, the reason you don't feel welcome is because you don't have the knowledge / aren't a professional server administrator so surely if you want to feel welcomed, you should well... become one? To put it another way, let's say I'm having a party and I've invited a bunch of friends and you (a complete stranger) happen to walk past and want to join in, if I say 'Sorry, only people who are invited or at the very least know me are invited.' am I now in danger of being unwelcoming? [– Script47](https://bit.ly/2ByOS7f)*

Comment: There's an argument to be made for a site's reputation preceding it.  There's also an argument to be made that you shouldn't judge a book by it's cover, which is what's happening here.

Comment: Meh.  As soon as you resort to, "unassailable" logic, as per that blog post, your argument is inherently flawed.

Comment: Ok, now that we have this piece of wisdom (that we already know about and has been discussed to the ends of the Earth already)...... what do we do with it? Because what you're saying here is basically "people who want to feel unwelcome should never be questioned as to the value of that feeling. The feeling is there, it's true, we must fix it". Then you'll have experts complaining about this pandering to the newbies to be unwelcoming to them (the experts). Who do you listen to here?

Comment: @fbueckert that's the logic SO is using. I'm just playing by the rules of the game

Comment: You can see how well that went for the vice president.  You sure you want to follow in those footsteps?

Comment: @fbueckert I'm not familiar to what you're alluding to.

Comment: @Patrice IMO, chasing the "welcoming" dragon is an exercise in futility. It's barking up the wrong tree. We should stop focusing on it entirely.

Comment: @Houseman 100% with you there. I think that kinda was where I was going with when I showed that expert's "unwelcomingness" may very well be newbie "welcomingness". The problem is that SO is a business, and that's how they want to see it. They want traffic, they want users. So "welcomingness", however much of a pipe dream it is, is very much at the forefront of their mind :/. To the detriment of the site I guess

Answer (score -52):

Sadly, this is another attempt at fixing the perception rather than the fundamental fact that the site is truly unwelcoming. If you want to know why people bitch on Twitter rather than coming here to complain, it's because there are gangs of moderators that support each other through any sort of inappropriate behavior.

I saw a new user get their question wrongly closed for a supposed duplicate, even though the other question referred to was substantially different (but one would have had to actually *read* them, rather than skim keywords). I tried to answer their question quickly so they at least got that, but it got wiped out in a flash.

And then I tried to point out that ugly process on meta, and the same people shut me down immediately. So I ended up leaving that site, because the bad faith put into dismissing my complaint was staggering.

It's not so much the closing of the questions that disturbs people as the dismissal without even trying to understand what the issue is.  You see a queue as something to get through as fast as possible, but it'd be better to have a longer queue and still remember those are people asking questions, not robots.  If you want to behave like a robot, program one, don't inflict your moods on others.

Comment: If you think that a question isn't a duplicate then explain why you think the duplicate fails to adequately answer the question, rather than just assuming that the person closing it didn't read it.

Comment: One question: when you approached meta, were you as vehement as you are here? That's a surefire way to not get what you want, even if the initial reason for you to do what you did was correct. (I'm not saying it's ok that's how it is.... but it's a reality).  But one thing I read here is again the focus on users, instead of posts. That's where a LOT of the breaks happen. The problem is that veterans (these mods you talk of) see the site as a way to get good *content* up, well rated, and visible. A lot of new users still just want **their** question answered, regardless of our intent

Comment: I hate wrongful dupe closures just as much as the next guy.  But taking the stance of this being intentional or malicious is only serving to reinforce your perception of us being unwelcoming as opposed to us being human and making mistakes.

Comment: @Makoto no no. Remember, users on this site are human. Except if you disagree with them. Then they are monsters.

Comment: @Patrice:  I've played the role of "monster" more times than I care to recall.  I can look myself in the mirror and know I'm human and have made mistakes, and I can be at peace with that.  They're the ones with the identity complex, not me. :)

Comment: @Makoto **exactly what a monster would say**.  Sarcasm aside, that's what's REALLY starting to rub me off with this whole welcoming shtick. New users are allowed to throw all kinds of tantrum, insult everyone along their way, be mean, disrespectful, and not care about this site or what made it a success over the years. But if they are a new user, they are absolved of most of this, simply because they are new users. Isn't that being MORE than welcoming?

Comment: I'd be more receptive of the issues if those that challenged the status quo actually tried to understand what SO is all about.  I can count on one hand the number of new users that posted a meta that actually do that.  Heck, we get many established users that still don't.  But plowing straight ahead and refusing to listen or accept that, hey, maybe SO doesn't quite work the way you think it does, doesn't help you, us, or anyone else.  It's just frustration all around, as you write SO off, we write you off, and nobody's happy.

Comment: `even though the other question referred to was substantially different` it is not about the questions.  If the ***answer*** in the linked dupe will work for this questions, there is no need to post another new answer.  There are 4,489 posts linked to the classic Net NRE.  I daresay many of them are different questions.  The *answer* is the same in almost all cases though since there is only 2 root causes for an [NRE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Could somebody explain why you have donwnvoted this opinion? Not because he  is unwelcome to say, isn't it? But at the same time you do not care that Georg M could understand it this way?

Comment: @Disaffected1070452 That is wrong. It's about both the question and the answers. If all possible answers to A are also possible answers to B, and vice versa, then they are duplicates. **If that is not true then they are not duplicates**. Just because an answer to another question is also a possible answer to the question you're looking at does not in itself make the question a duplicate. All possible answers to the duplicate also have to be possible answers for the target and vice versa.

Comment: @Roman on meta, where votes are expected to show agreement as much as the usual signals.... I think it's normal to downvote stuff people don't agree on. Does that mean we downvote him? Does that mean we tell him 'go away'? No, not at all. He is entirely welcome at having an opinion different than mine. Am I not welcome to also express my opinion? Have we gone so far off the deep end that 'disagreeing' is now 'unwelcoming'?

Comment: @Patrice, I am asking do you bother of his understanding your downvotes? I do not have any expectations, just want to collect some replies to think about them later. As I understand you: on SO and on Meta downvoting has different meaning and everybody should know it, if not - theirs problem.

Comment: @Roman you're putting words in my mouth here. Big ones. Actually ones I do not agree with, so calm down with the inference plz. And I can understand his understanding of downvotes and still disagree (as I currently do). Am I unwelcoming by using the very tools I was given to express that opinion? I will never believe I am.

Comment: He thinks, like so many before, that there is an evil crew on stack and meta that likes the site the way it is and that do a sort of confirmation bias amongst themselves, where any 'disagreeing' idea is shut down. Yeah, I get that. And God knows that it can look like that very easily. The one problem I keep on seeing here is the difference between what newer users feel the site is about, vs what veterans think. As long as we don't reconcile these two, nothing will move forward.

Comment: @Patrice mmm... didn't get you... could I repeat the q again?  Do you bother of his understanding your downvotes?

Comment: @Roman very ambiguous phrasing, considering that sentence doesn't mean anything :/. Either you ask me if I bother to understand how he sees downvotes (if so, check my comment just above I explain it) or you ask me if I am bothered by his view of my downvotes. If that is your question, no I am not bothered at all. No more than I am bothered if someone misinterprets me and decides to be angry because of a misunderstanding....

Comment: @Patrice thank you. I should say I do not see any reason to downvote/speak/ start any social interaction if you are not interested in to send correct message to your opponent and not interested in to doublecheck correctness. But the same time I can't do any conclusions right now.

Comment: @Roman fair point. But how much should I assume that my interlocutor knows? (Opponent gives of a very combative vibe I can't agree to use). The second I get asked for a justification or explanation, I will be the first one to give one. I just don't assume by default that people don't know. Again, does that make me unwelcoming? I don't see how. The burden of communication lies in both parties, not entirely on us..... Also downvoted aren't a 'social interaction'. In most cases. Only on meta can they be seen as one IMHO (in line with downvote = disagree).

Comment: Seriously? I'd estimate that fully half of the questions on the tags that I follow could be closed as duplicates, and a good chunk of those are *exact* duplicates. If the expectation is that you should be able to copy an answer and simply paste it over your existing code in order for it not to be a "duplicate", then maybe the site should be renamed "Mechanical Turk Exchange". Most of the time I can find a solid dup target by ***Googling the question title***.

Comment: Disagree, I had a lot of problems in the beginning myselft, but I got through them by learning. I have seen some trolls, but they aren't enough to make a difference if you figure out how to format well and be usefully origina.