# Should one comprehensive document/guide for the "Recommended Rules of Etiquette" be created and maintained for new users?

Tags: feature-request

Should one comprehensive document/guide for the "Recommended Rules of Etiquette" be created by a group of moderators and experienced users that is carefully maintained for new users?

The document/guide for the "Recommended Rules of Etiquette" could supplement the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: [This already exists](https://stackoverflow.com/help).

Comment: I am not convinced creating yet another doc no one will read will help improve more than the slew of docs we already have on that topic..

Comment: And this does nothing to solve the fact that new users don't read, and you can't make them.

Comment: One thing you might want to read is https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/377101/can-we-be-more-welcoming-by-managing-expectations

Comment: Are we going down the "etiquette" road again? Wasn't your last question about etiquette just a mess because people focused on that word instead of the rest? +.... how does naming it "etiquette" change anything about the feedback you already got? (a) it already exists, b) no one reads these things anyway...)

Comment: @Patrice I have edited my original question to make it more specific. I believe my original question was too broad. My original question was: "Should a "Recommended/Best Practices Guide" be created and maintained for new users?".

Comment: @COrNotToC your original question didn't contain etiquette. My comment came after your revision which added the word "etiquette". I don't see the edit helping in any way to address any of the feedback already given. a) it already exists, b) it's not read or used enough.  How is naming it "etiquette" instead of "rules of conduct" addressing this?

Comment: Isn't that also what we capture in [meta-tag:FAQ] posts?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Should one comprehensive downloadable document be created that includes every page in the Help Center?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/378740/should-one-comprehensive-downloadable-document-be-created-that-includes-every-pa)

Comment: Also not a duplicate of your newer question.  I'm having trouble seeing your motivation for this; what do you believe something like this will accomplish?

Answer (score 3):

My greatest fear is that no one will actually take the time to *comprehend* the document, its reason for existence, or follow its advice.  Well, that's happening today anyway; I suppose my fear is simply exacerbated by the added sting of being called "rude" when I'm only attempting to tell them, "Hey, you need more details in your question or it's gonna get closed, y'know."

Comment: How dare you say that to users though? What are you trying to do? *be helpful*?!

Comment: @Patrice: Yep, that's a bit much of me.  I'm sorry and I will endeavor to comment less in the future. :)