# Automatic comment if new user's question is down voted more than once

Tags: discussion, new-users, automatic-comments

Sure, we have a system in place that prevents a question from being asked if it "looks like there isn't enough code".

But, I noticed that there is a lot of situations where people will have to leave a comment suggesting the OP include more code that relates to their question if there isn't enough or less if it's out of scope.

Then there are times when a new user's question is downvoted but nothing is said about it.

I think we should have a system in place where a comment will be left, welcoming the user and pointing to [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [creating an MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) if the question reaches a score of -2 or lower.

This would save a lot of people time from just repeating the typical "Welcome to SO. Do X, please."

**Similar situations where this could be applied:**

- 2 or more close votes
- When the Tumbleweed badge [would have been](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/06/18/adios-to-unfriendly-badges-ahoy-lifejacket-and-lifeboat/) triggered

*The actual numbers don't matter so much, it is the principle of considering this implementation.*

Comment: `Welcome to SO. Do X, please.` If the X that the OP needs to do to improve the question could indeed be accurately identified, sure, but auto-comments aren't capable of that (yet)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Of all the comments to leave on a question, ["Welcome to Stack Overflow; please do X"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/340103/1079354) is probably the last one I'd want *automated*.

Questions get downvoted for a plethora of reasons:

- The question isn't well researched, or otherwise not useful (what the tooltip suggests)
- The question is poorly written
- The question is incomplete or a "give me teh codez"-style question

...and automating which one makes the most sense in a given context is impossible, since it could *not* be any of those reasons at all.

If your motivation is to "save people time" from commentating to the effect of, "Please do X", then I feel like your motivation is misplaced.  The fact that someone has to say that at all is ***backwards***.  A user should understand why their question isn't suitable for the site, and that can only *really* come from better UX, which is allegedly being worked on now.

Answer (score 13):

A problem I see with this idea is that [actionable suggestions about specific issues](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/365930/2751851) tend to be more useful when it comes to providing guidance to new users than generic comments directing them to general purpose help pages (see [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/367861/2751851) for an extended argument on the matter). For instance, there is no way an automated procedure can tell if telling the user to add an MCVE is actually a relevant suggestion in the context of a specific question. That being so, the kind of comment you describe isn't, or at any rate shouldn't be, repetitive boilerplate that can be uniformly replaced.