# How can generic questions in Stackoverflow have thousands of upvotes when this is something unacceptable?

Tags: discussion, canonical, old-questions

Below you can see a great example of this:

> [image]

There are no examples of what the user tried, no specifications, nothing. Just a "tutorial" question. How is this possible?

Comment: Canonical questions do be like that and the age.

Comment: Could when the question was asked have something to do with it?

Comment: cross site related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/201716/diminishing-returns-non-linear-reputation-from-great-answers

Comment: 5.7 million views, 0.13% of the visitors voted.  Google used to like us, as did experts with a "thank heavens, I'll never have to explain *that* again" mission.

Comment: Asked nine years ago.

Comment: @rene just because it's an old question doesn't mean it's good. We need to purge all questions above a certain number of upvotes from SO imho

Comment: @user234461 why would you want to purge the questions that have - demonstrably through community voting - helped the most people on SO? Actually asking. What would that accomplish?

Comment: @user234461 that sounds like we would destroy lots of valuable content, not exactly what SO set out for as their mission for future visitors

Comment: Google "How to check if a string contains another string" and this is the first stack overflow link - with an answer that works. Seems like this question does its job to me.

Comment: @user234461 so we delete [14 questions](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1100654?cutoff=7432) then?

Comment: @rene but you just admitted that the only reason the question is upvoted and not instantly flagged is that it is old. Either a question is good or it isn't. If similar styles of question get downvoted or removed now, then by your argument they are bad, and if they are bad now then they were bad then.

Comment: @user234461 I did not admit anything. Don't spin something I didn't say for your own agenda. Not appreciated.

Comment: @user234461 "We need to purge questions above a certain number of upvotes" WAIT WHAT? So once a question becomes **really** helpful to future visitors.... we trash it? That's... counterproductive to the very goal of stack.

Comment: @user234461 a question being good depends heavily on the information context surrounding it. If information does not exist about a topic at the time that the question is asked then SO can serve as the canonical/encyclopedic answer. If information exists elsewhere the question probably demonstrates a lack of research. I'm not even sure why I'm belaboring this point since it's been said many times on this page but it's really bothering me that anyone would not understand this idea.

Comment: see also: [How on Earth can this kind of question be so appreciated?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/316604/839601)

Comment: @HFBrowning If a question is a duplicate, close it as a duplicate. But that's not what's being discussed here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That question has that many votes because it's very, very old. The site was a year and half old, still learning how to walk. It didn't have that many questions, and quality standards and rules had not set in. Since then it received almost 6 million visitors, and a tiny fraction of those decided to vote on it.

If you asked the same question today, you'd be very likely downvoted, yes. And you couldn't fault the downvoters. Today, finding the answer to that question is much, much easier than back then, so it would not be wrong to say that the question was *very* poorly researched (which is one of the reasons we have to downvote a question).

But not only that: I think the argument could be made for the question to receive close-votes as "too-broad" as well.

Because the question, in its simplicity, it's not adequately scoped. There are many, many ways to accomplish that simple task. Different JS engines. Many libraries. Multiple frameworks. The question lacks detail, like if the asker cares about case-sensitivity, repeat patterns, cares about newlines, etc, etc, etc.

If the question were not locked, it would have received dozens of answers by now, most of them repetitive and of poor quality. There are other examples of this.

You could say: well, if a question is "generic" and doesn't provide any details or constraints, any answer is valid, right? It is in fact a very answerable question!

But even it doesn't need an entire book nor a complete tutorial as an answer; there are **too many valid answers** for that question, and no way to determine which one, if any, is correct.

And in real life, very simple, not properly scoped questions have a very nasty tendency to mutate as they receive answers and comments, and a scope begins to emerge. That many, many times, is completely different from the scope that the first answerers/commenters tried to divine.

There is another very famous question that could be used as example of a simple "generic" question. It was posted by one of the founders of the site to *"prove"* that the site was open to beginners as well as experts, and to show that this simple, how-to questions were a good fit for the site:

[How do I move the turtle in LOGO?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1003841/how-do-i-move-the-turtle-in-logo)

There was a lot of back and forth regarding that question, but it was eventually closed and locked. I think who best explained why this question was no good, was [the other founder](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158289/why-is-the-how-to-move-the-turtle-in-logo-question-closed#comment457933_158334):

> Simple is fine. No effort and research is not

But that statement was made many years ago, and we made ample progress in defining *why* this type of question is no good.

We know now it is not about "effort" and "research" on themselves, what we care about are the resultant artifacts: details, context and scoping that allow potential answers to provide **useful, verifiable answers**.

And yet, the turtle notwithstanding, **how-to questions are fine**. And they do not **necessarily** need code. But they do need to be **adequately scoped**.

(Many times they most certainly benefit from code though, it makes it easier and clearer for answerers, so they can understand what you are trying to accomplish, and properly situate themselves to be able to post rich, meaningful, useful answers; this is a programmer's website after all: most of our issues do deal around code, even if the question is not about *"debug this for me please"*.)

Comment: Ouch. That's quite a bit of rambling. My apologies.

Comment: I'm not disappointed by this rambling. Please continue ...

Answer (score 7):

> There are no examples of what the user tried

This is fine.

"How to" questions do not need to exhibit a failed attempt, and never have. I personally think that failed attempts typically make such questions worse, by warping them into weird hybrid questions that are sort of asking how to do the thing in the title and sort of asking us to debug the failed attempt.

> no specifications

The problem seems to be specified well enough for 7432 upvoters to understand what's being asked and for people to be able to answer it. What further specification do you think it's missing?

> Just a "tutorial" question.

What do you mean by a "tutorial" question? I'd understand that to be a question that is asking for a tutorial. But this clearly is not such a question. It's a narrow question about how to do one specific thing, potentially answerable with a one-liner.

Comment: If I ask the same question on StackOverflow it will get many downvotes because reasons...

Comment: @user3858890 Possibly. *Some* users do downvote "how to" questions that don't exhibit a failed attempt. I find that behaviour profoundly annoying and counterproductive, and rail against it.

Comment: So in few words there are no specific rules on asking questions on this website...great!!

Comment: @user3858890 I'd say there is no commonly defined consensus upon which everyone reliably acts. It's really up to the people that see your question. Some, if they have that issue, will upvote because it helps them. Others will try to close, or delete because "it didn't show effort" (even though effort has not and is never a reason to close a question).  It's effectively roulette, unfortunately.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker Your comment is the perfect answer for my question! If you want put it as an answer to accept it.

Comment: '*If I ask the same question on StackOverflow it will get many downvotes because reasons...*' - Not because "reasons", rather, because it has been asked before and because it's very easy to find with a Google search. I'd personally disagree with @GeorgeStocker and say it isn't as much as a roulette as it might seem.

Comment: @user3858890 *"If I ask the same question on StackOverflow it will get many downvotes"* That question was asked a decade ago. It was a non-duplicate question back then. There are 1.8 million javascript questions on SO now. If you ask something that basic now, it means you have not done [enough research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users/261593#261593). And the site rules have evolved in the last decade.

Comment: There are also different levels of how-to questions. "How do I write an operating system" -> too broad. Other how-to questions that need only a few lines of explanation and code might be fine. Problem is: if you ask the question, you often don't know if it's too broad or not.

Comment: *"if you ask the question, you often don't know if it's too broad or not"* - obligatory XKCD: https://xkcd.com/1425/. That said, I think a thoughtful asker can *usually* tell how broad their question is, especially if they've done some research before asking it.

Comment: I'm actually surprised to see that "there are no examples of what a user tried" is fine. I'm not arguing your point, I just don't think that's well communicated at all. For the past 3 years of my use of SO I always assumed I'd have to include a failed attempt.

Comment: @WarpDriveEnterprises isn't the attempt implied (though it seems quite explicit)? They looked for a `contains` method which didn't exist.

Comment: I think a problem here is that some people want a template approach, when there isn't one. It requires judgement - *like everything else in programming*. I have seen similarly "generic", recent questions on newer languages that I thought were very good questions, and others did too (they were upvoted). The common denominator? The information existed nowhere else: not in the new language's API, not in the documentation, or other SO questions. So the answerer had to provide expert insight to help.

Comment: @Script47 Yeah, that is true. I've just seen posts with very similar attempts be closed/downvoted.

Comment: @WarpDriveEnterprises the question in question seems to be the first of its type and that's why it was so well received. Now, when I type into Google '*string contains javascript*', that is the second result I see which is excellent because it means that SO is serving its purpose through that question.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker Lack of effort may not be a close reason but it is very explicitly a downvote reason, which is what the OP commented about.

Answer (score 5):

Today, if you would ask that question, it would be downvoted because you haven't shown *any attempt to do minimal research*. A [quick google](https://www.google.com/search?q=substeing+contaisn+string+js&oq=substeing+contaisn+string+js&aqs=chrome..69i57.4549j0j7&client=ms-android-hmd-rev2&sourceid=chrome-mobile&ie=UTF-8) already leads you to an answer, here on SO. Right, the one you are talking about.

It's fine to ask about "How to do XY in language Z?", as long as you are the first one to do so.

Comment: Even with that misspelling!