# Why is this question not closed?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, old-questions

When I was new to Stack Overflow, and asked a question not related to programming, my question was marked as off-topic and closed.

Recently when I was searching on Stack Overflow, I have found many old, similar questions (not programming related) which have gained many votes & answers.

One example is: [What are metaclasses in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/100003/what-are-metaclasses-in-python) which contains just one line:

> What are metaclasses and what do we use them for?

for which the OP can search on Google & get many good answers. Despite this, such questions sometimes get more than 5000 votes, as well as answers. To this day, the above question is not marked as closed.

If I were to ask the same kind of question now, I suspect my question will be marked as off-topic and closed instantly.

Are there any specific reasons behind the differing approaches between old and new questions?

Am I allowed to ask such just one-lined questions?

Comment: The rules evolved over time, but such questions are too valiable (traffic-wise) to be simply removed. You have to follow current rules, so no - you can't ask same *broad* questions.

Comment: I would also say that a question like _What's this concept_ is not off-topic by default. It might attract a lot of  downvotes due to poor research, or get closed as too broad if it's a broad concept, but if it hasn't been asked before, is a narrowly-defined concept and you can't easily get the definition and use by doing research, asking about it might lead to a well-received question.

Comment: Currently If I have difficulty to find proper meaning of some new technical word then should I ask like 'what is this concept about to get more clearity ?

Comment: @Moon perhaps you could ask here about the specific question you want to ask, rather than generalities?

Comment: It's kinda hard to be a repository of programming knowledge if some programming knowledge is off limits.  None of us are able to say "That's too easy to be on Stack Overflow" because it's different for every person that visits the site.  Personally I'm very happy that we don't have a "it's too easy" close reason.  We know and trust our site and our vetting process for answers; but the rest of the internet has not yet adopted that method of operating.  Ours is the best way that exists to figure out good knowledge from bad knowledge. we should capitalize on that, not shun it.

Comment: I appreciate SO. I have gained much knowledge & help from others too since my joining on SO so I don't have any intention to criticize anyone or SO's method but I have seen above kind of different kind of approach so I have asked question so please don't take it as negatively. May be many other new users also have same question.

Comment: Related (duplicate?): [How can generic questions in Stackoverflow have thousands of upvotes when this is something unacceptable?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/389156/1364007)

Answer (score 12):

> Recently when I was searching on SO, I have found many old, similar questions (not programming related) which have gained many votes & answers.
>
> The above question contains simply one line:
>
> > What are metaclasses and what do we use them for?

For starters, this question *is* related to programming. I'm not sure why you don't think that's the case.

Second, Stack Overflow aims to be a repository of all specifically-scoped questions. While this is a short (some may say basic) question, it's still scoped to ask an objectively-answerable thing: 'what is  and what is its use-case'.

> If I were to ask the same kind of question now, I suspect my question will be marked as off-topic and closed instantly.

Well, it would be problematic if you asked the *exact same* thing, because then it would be a duplicate. However, just because a question is basic or perhaps googleable does not make it *off-topic* for Stack Overflow. How to center an HTML element via CSS is extremely basic but also not off-topic.

A couple principles to keep in mind here:

- Just because something is "googleable" doesn't mean it's off-topic. From SO's perspective, they definitely want it to be googleable... *here*; I'm sure they'd prefer when someone google's *any* programming question that the top result is to a Stack Overflow question. It increases the site's value for people and also means more page views, ads, and potential customers.
- In the same vein, if something is simple or googleable and *ought* to be findable elsewhere (and not a self-answered/Community Wiki Q/A), the term you're looking for is "lack of research". Importantly, lack of research is a *downvote* reason, not a *close vote* reason.

Comment: yeah. I want to say 'broad' or 'lack of research'! Above answers & comments clear my doubts as well. Thanks!

Comment: does "lack of research" reason apply to when they found reference on other site and not on SO?

Comment: @Shinjo What do you mean by 'finding reference'?

Comment: @TylerH Like when you ask about "how does A work" it wasn't found on SO but you can find them in either official documentation or random github issue explaining that.

Comment: @Shinjo Sure; keep in mind each person's threshold for what constitutes "enough research" might be different. Some people think SO is fine as a first stop; most of us think you should search exhaustively and ask here only as a last resort.

Answer (score 4):

[Question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/100003/10961238) which you are talking about is asked in 2008, the days when [Stack Overflow](https://www.google.com/search?q=stackoverflow%20found%20date&rlz=1C1CHBD_enIN833IN833&oq=stackoverflow%20found%20date&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i64.6260j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) just started, almost 11 years old question. At that time site was *learning* how to handle the posts and how we can have a cleaner site where anyone can easily find a solution and that's what we all want.

The question has more than 5k upvotes shows that it was helpful to the community. Now if you asked the one-line question now, I am sure it will be closed or removed. Because during the journey of 11 years site has [learned](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) how to keep it clean with the help of the community reviews.