# Why this question is well received?

Tags: discussion

Question *[What is the &#xA; character?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5541222/what-is-the-xa-character)* doesn't show any effort at all, but it's still being upvoted. Why is it protected instead of closed?

Comment: Because people search google and that comes up. I don't see how it is closeable, it is a clear, on-topic, answerable programming question.

Comment: But it doesn't show any effort and I got told many time that a question which doesn't show effort is not a good question.

Comment: The site has changed over time.  That used to be okay.  Now, not so much (that doesn't mean never, just it is not as frequent).  It doesn't *need* to be closed as it isn't causing any problems and there is enough new problems that *need* to be closed.

Comment: Low effort questions can be useful over time, even if asked today.

Comment: "showing effort" and "helpful" are independent from each other. SO only tolerates questions that "show effort". But anything that's "helpful" tend to get upvoted.

Comment: My question is obviously pointing the finger against the "the community is always right and the OP is always wrong" behaviour. Sometime sounds really like a ranting the attempt to force some explanations.

Comment: Guys, it's always the same answers. @NathanOliver: there are 5 - 6 standard answers used in many cases which are simply not fitting the reality. My question is a provocation to show how much looks like a ranting the effort of self justifying the community.

Comment: @Mysticial: as you can see SO tolerate maaaany questions showing no effort. Many questions I opened showed no effort.

Comment: It's just funny trying to find a justification where there isn't any.. this was the real point here.

Comment: @Revious, I don't fully understand what exactly is your point...

Comment: @Revious The site has changed over the time. In the past (5+ years ago), almost everything was allowed. Not anymore though. If you asked a low-effort question now, it'll probably get killed regardless of whether it's actually useful.

Comment: @yivi: a few days ago I got a non constructive answer by some high rep user (or mod) they were trying to state (exactly as now) that they were right. One of the thesis was that: "questions that doesn't show effort are bad questions". Now people are trying other explanation but the point in common is that SO politics start by assuming that the OP is wrong and by pushing this idea in an excessive way.

Comment: @Mysticial: I know very well, I'm an user since some years and I got many complains since years. The explanations years ago and now were: "The site has changed over the time" . The funniest part is that the question is my most upvoted one and it's still being costantly upvoted.

Comment: Why this inability to say: "community members are not always right, they may make mistakes?"

Comment: But you are not proving anything. Your question, asked today, is a terrible question. Votes do not prove that your question is "good". They only prove someone chose to up vote it, despite being a terrible question.

Comment: @yivi: it's being costantly upvoted. The last upvote just today ;) u.u

Comment: Alright, I'll feed the troll. So you're trying to say that the "community is wrong". Can you clarify what it is they are wrong about?

Comment: Another question from the past.. this had been strongly downvoted because of the lack of effort. Mmm.. wasn't the website different in the past? 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26655534/what-is-catcomplete-in-jquerys-autocomplete-plugin

Comment: @Revious What does that matter?  Yivi's point still stands.  People ask bad questions, and some people upvote those bad questions, even though they're bad questions.  It's unfortunate, but it happens.

Comment: Are you trying to prove SO is not rigorously consistent? It is a community moderated site. What a surprise...

Comment: @Mysticial: yes, the community is often emotional, wrong, incoherent as every human being and if this is pretty obvious it's a problema that it's also unable to admit it. This is a real issue. Trying to make the OP always appear as 'guilty' of a bad behavior is really unconstructive.

Comment: @yivi: but you are really one of the very very few to admit this.. isn't an issue that most of the mod and high rep community member always back up each other? Do they need to state they are right? Wouldn't be better to issue this problem?

Comment: @Revious So you're saying that it's inappropriate to assert that the author of a question is responsible for its quality because sometimes people upvote bad questions?  That...doesn't follow.  That some people upvote questions, even though they're bad, doesn't remove the responsibility of a question author to ask a good question.

Comment: @Revious You'll find almost any regular user of the site will freely indicate that voting can be inconsistent.  You've seen *many* people say as much in your other meta questions, so your assertion that others don't acknowledge it is false, and you know it's false.

Comment: No, that second question got downvoted because the first couple of revisions were awful, then it got hit HARD by the meta effect.

Comment: You should expect low effort questions to initially be received poorly. If they survive the initial period, and are found to be useful, overtime the upvotes may outweigh the downvotes.

Comment: @Servy: no, that absolutely not what I'm stating. I'm stating that community member are often emotional and the mod and high rep users should absolutely stop trying to defend them and back up with each other. They should try to be constructive. To be sure about what they are answering and don't use always standard answers. They should make an effort when it's needed or don't answer at all.

Comment: @Revious That you personally would prefer that people either answer or do nothing, and never give feedback on the quality of a question, is very strongly *opposed* to the design of the site, and its goals.  There are many other sites out there that have no mechanisms at all for critiquing or evaluating questions, and only allow users to answer it.  SO isn't one of those sites, and doesn't *want* to be one of those sites.

Comment: It doesn't matter so much but I find Servy, Mysticial Patrice's answer to be a bit superficial (not making any real effort), while Kevin B, yivi to be very more useful. Why not trying to be constructive?

Comment: i mean... i don't disagree with servy/mystical/patrice in this case either. All of their responses are along the same lines as mine. I never said the questions were "good" questions.

Comment: @KevinB: they stated in another question that questions which don't show efforts are completely bad.

Comment: I don't disagree with that. useful, and good/quality aren't the same metric.

Comment: So can you explain why you just wrote the opposite? https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/356399/why-this-question-is-well-received#comment513064_356399

Comment: Bad questions can be useful. Good questions can be not useful. those are two separate metrics by which people cast votes.

Comment: Ok, you edited. But so a question which is useful is NOT a good question. Interesting point of view..

Comment: @KevinB: and people can be wrong, can be emotional and they are absolutely not always right, as well as it's a huge oversimplification to state that a question which doesn't document the effort is "bad" and so on and so on. Don't you agree?

Comment: well, it could be. you could have a very poorly written question that is hard to understand, that ends up being wildly useful because it contains a good answer and a title that attracts users with said problem. That would make it bad, but useful.

Comment: @Revious The reason why you're getting "superficial" responses from some of us is because we get asked the same question so many times that we're all tired of giving the same responses over and over again. In the vast majority of such cases, the OPs asking them are not acting in good faith. So they get treated appropriately.

Comment: It's hard for me to judge questions on usefulness at this point, so i typically ignore that metric and judge by quality alone. i suspect i'm not alone in that. That's probably why you'll see low effort questions that are initially poorly received, and then over time upvoted. The early voters vote on quality, and then over time people vote based on usefulness; whether or not it helped solved their problem. Some end up being useful, others don't.

Comment: I'm one of the few who ascribe to the school of thought that such questions as the one linked in your question here are actually good for the site. The problem is that—by now—most such questions have already been asked. You seem to be focusing on "effort" which is actually [a conflation of the three types of effort](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260909/4639281). Research effort **only matters with regards to research on Stack Overflow**, meaning that if the answer cannot be found _on Stack Overflow_, the question cannot be lacking in research effort. If it can be, it is a duplicate.

Comment: See the linked post in my last comment for more information on the three types of effort, and what can be done when a question is lacking in any one or multiple of those three.

Comment: It won the Google lottery, it is the top hit for "&#xA".  That produced eighty-thousand views over the past 6 years, a bit less than 1 in a thousand of those visitors thought it was good enough to upvote.  The SO community had little to do with it.  Having answers found back by Google queries is rather the point of the site, the good stuff easily gets half a million views.

Comment: see also: [Should I downvote old, low-quality answers/questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/258800/839601)

Comment: Generally, if you ask a question on meta in good faith, constructively, you'll get a good reception. Asking a question in obvious bad faith, without actually addressing any of the arguments others have made, just makes it look like you're pushing your agenda. I, for one, am tired of it.

Comment: @fbueckert wait.. this question wasn't opened in good faith?! paint me surprised... (/sarcasm)

Answer (score 10):

> it's still being upvoted

Because, ostensibly, people find it and its answer useful, despite the fact that your question is a one-liner with no demonstration of research effort or indeed, any exposition whatsoever. Your question has been around for a while; any research would actually lead *to your question* at this point, so most folks would be more willing to overlook the lack of research effort part for that reason alone.

> protected

Got me. Maybe because the question has been sufficiently answered and the last (only) deleted answer was spam, and the user who protected your question felt that the odds that any new user with < 10 rep would contribute a better answer than what's already been given is practically zero.

> instead of closed

It's on-topic.

Comment: On the protected front, I'm really not seeing much evidence that it *needs* to be protected, since there's only one deleted answer there.  I don't see reason to lift it either since it's well-answered and new answers would only parrot what they see, though.

Comment: @Makoto: Yeah, I don't think the question needs protecting either. I'm just kinda lazy to unprotect it.

Comment: So you agree with what Kevin B stated? - "Low effort questions can be useful over time, even if asked today." - Can you explain me why many high rep user didn't get this point still today?
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/356399/why-this-question-is-well-received#comment513064_356399

Comment: Answer: "yes", put this concept black on white, make a guideline for them!

Comment: @Revious Low effort questions can be useful, sometimes. But generally, they are not. Personally, I can't imagine your question being useful to the desirable SO target audience (_enthusiasts and professionals_), but hey, any random person may come along and vote you up anyway.

Comment: @yivi: I like that you said that you can't imagine, many other high rep users would have wrote: "it's just like that". I like SO, but I fear Quora will get a huge advantage due to this politic. Some years ago everyone was replying that "we are not YA". Nowaday with Quora and Quag I didn't get this answer anymore.

Comment: In my opinion the problem is that this community is very compact in its ideas, but sometime this make it very hard to change even the smaller idea and.. you know it's the survival of the fittest. The community instead is extremely rigid.

Comment: @Revious Sounds like the best approach is to let it play out and see which philosophy endures and which fades.

Comment: @Revious Stack Overflow and Quora are two very different things that serve two very different purposes (with some overlap). If you favor quora's openness (and corresponding lack of anything resembling quality) then you should stick to quora. If you want quality (and are willing to accept Stack Overflow's lack of openness), then you should stick with Stack Overflow. The implied point here is that we are what we are, and we have what we have, because we are the way we are, and we do things the way we do them.

Comment: @TinyGiant: improvements in quality of SO are not welcome? Here it's not a matter of SO has a big quality, but more that it raise strong defense when someone shows his problematics.